# How to set the font style to bold, italic and underlined in an Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, text-styling

I want to make a `TextView`'s content bold, italic and underlined. I tried the following code and it works, but doesn't underline.

```
<Textview android:textStyle="bold|italic" ..
```

How do I do it? Any quick ideas?

Comment: does it work to set just one of them?

Comment: yes working fine i also want to make it under line.

Comment: textView.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

Comment: `tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);`

Comment: [Underline TextView - 5 Amazing ways](https://androidride.com/underline-a-textview-in-android/)

Answer (score 309, accepted):

I don't know about underline, but for bold and italic there is `"bolditalic"`. There is no mention of underline here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle

Mind you that to use the mentioned `bolditalic` you need to, and I quote from that page

> Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values.

so you'd use `bold|italic`

You could check this question for underline: [Can I underline text in an android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)

Comment: for under line..
 `textView.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);`

Comment: @bala be aware that your solution always underlines the whole text, so it's not feasible in cases when one wants to underline just a portion of it.

Comment: Using xml instead of doing it by code is preferred when possible. See Andro Selva's answer below

Answer (score 398):

This should make your TextView **bold**, **underlined** and ***italic*** at the same time.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="register"><u><b><i>Copyright</i></b></u></string>
</resources>
```

To set this String to your TextView, do this in your **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/register" />
```

or In **JAVA**,

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(R.string.register);
```

Sometimes the above approach will not be helpful when you might have to use Dynamic Text. So in that case [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) comes into action.

```
String tempString="Copyright";
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
text.setText(spanString);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I checked it in 2.1. So at least it should work from 2.1 and above

Comment: Can consider using `new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)`

Comment: Why it's not work on dynamic concatenated string? It's wired that some numbers appeared....

Answer (score 179):

Or just like this in Kotlin:

```
val tv = findViewById(R.id.textViewOne) as TextView
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD or Typeface.ITALIC)
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC)
// AND
tv.paintFlags = tv.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
```

Or in Java:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewOne);
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD|Typeface.ITALIC);
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
// OR
tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
// AND
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()|Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Keep it simple and in one line :)

Comment: By inserting the kotlinx.android.synthetic package for the view you are working with, the findViewByID is not necessary in Kotlin, making each of the setTypeface lines: textViewOne.setTypeface(...)

Comment: is `paintFlags` necessary ? It's working without that

Answer (score 86):

For bold and italic whatever you are doing is correct for underscore use following code

HelloAndroid.java

```
 package com.example.helloandroid;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.SpannableString;
 import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
TextView textview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getText(R.string.hello));
    content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
    textview.setText(content);
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <string name="hello">Hello World, HelloAndroid!</string>
  <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: To remove the `underline` pass Null value instead of the `new UnderlineSpan()` as following  `content.setSpan(null, 0, content.length(), 0);`

Answer (score 51):

This is an easy way to add an underline, while maintaining other settings:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution always underlines the whole text, so it's not feasible in cases when one wants to underline just a portion of it.

Answer (score 49):

Programmatialy:

You can do programmatically using setTypeface() method:

Below is the code for default Typeface

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

and if you want to set custom Typeface:

```
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);      // for Normal Text
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);        // for Bold only
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);      // for Italic
textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC); // for Bold and Italic
```

XML:

You can set Directly in XML file in  like:

```
android:textStyle="normal"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:textStyle="normal|italic"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textStyle="bold|italic"
```

Comment: How can i change font family using setTypeface also apply bold,italic,underline ?

Comment: @DPrince look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 27):

**If you are reading that text from a file or from the network.**

You can achieve it by adding HTML tags to your text like mentioned

```
This text is <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b>
and <u>underlined</u> <b><i><u>bolditalicunderlined</u></b></i>
```

and then you can use the [HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class that processes HTML strings into displayable styled text.

```
// textString is the String after you retrieve it from the file
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textString));
```

Comment: fromHtml(String) method was deprecated in API level 24
More discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n

Answer (score 21):

Without quotes works for me:

```
<item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
```

Answer (score 15):

Just one line of code in xml

`android:textStyle="italic"`

Comment: This is the modern (2020+) solution 

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve it easily by using Kotlin's `buildSpannedString{}` under its `core-ktx` dependency.

```
val formattedString = buildSpannedString {
    append("Regular")
    bold { append("Bold") }
    italic { append("Italic") }
    underline { append("Underline") }
    bold { italic {append("Bold Italic")} }
}

textView.text = formattedString
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle
```

- by making this style, u can achieve underlining

Answer (score 0):

The community answer and the answer by Vivek have introduced the `SpannableString` class. This works, but what if you want more flexibility to build the string piece by piece, with different styles/effects in each piece, in `StringBuilder` style?

Is there something like `StringBuilder` for spannable strings? It turns out there is. Morgan Koh's answer explains it for Kotlin. In Java, we can do it too, something like

```
  SpannableStringBuilder myString = new SpannableStringBuilder().append("this in bold",boldSpan,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  myString.append("\n\nThis line in regular text\n\n");
```