# How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, typeface

So I'd like to change the `android:fontFamily` in Android but I don't see any pre-defined fonts in Android. How do I select one of the pre-defined ones? I don't really need to define my own TypeFace but all I need is something different from what it shows right now.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HeaderText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="CallerBlocker"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:fontFamily="Arial"
 />
```

It seems what I did up there won't really work! BTW `android:fontFamily="Arial"` was a stupid attempt!

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/48642116#48642116

Answer (score 1750, accepted):

From android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0, the following [Roboto](https://material.google.com/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html) font families are available:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

[image]

in combination with

```
android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
```

this 16 variants are possible:

- Roboto regular
- Roboto italic
- Roboto bold
- Roboto bold italic
- Roboto-Light
- Roboto-Light italic
- Roboto-Thin
- Roboto-Thin italic
- Roboto-Condensed
- Roboto-Condensed italic
- Roboto-Condensed bold
- Roboto-Condensed bold italic
- Roboto-Black
- Roboto-Black italic
- Roboto-Medium
- Roboto-Medium italic

`fonts.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="font_family_light">sans-serif-light</string>
    <string name="font_family_medium">sans-serif-medium</string>
    <string name="font_family_regular">sans-serif</string>
    <string name="font_family_condensed">sans-serif-condensed</string>
    <string name="font_family_black">sans-serif-black</string>
    <string name="font_family_thin">sans-serif-thin</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Don't forget this: android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin" // roboto thin

Comment: I saw a variant called "black small caps" in the [roboto specimen book](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/design/Roboto_Specimen_Book_20111129.pdf), but I don't manage to use it. Using `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black-small-caps"` doesnt work. Does someone know?

Comment: i am not able to find any of these font-family what have you typed here .i am not able to find "sans-serif" together.

Comment: This is a nice list. Does anyone have a link to where this information comes from? It would be nice if Google had this in their documentation in an easy to find place, say for the documentation of `android:fontFamily` on TextView.

Comment: Any clue of what's the source of this answer's information? I'd like to read further about it

Comment: This would be great information for, oh I don't know, how about **the `TextView` API Javadocs**.  Just sayin'.  Apparently [this is the only official reference](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html).

Comment: Is it accurate to say that ``fontFamily`` supercedes ``typeface``? Are we now no longer able to use serif or monospace? I don't think ``typeface`` is formally deprecated, just ignored when ``fontFamily`` is also present.

Comment: I have updated this answer with details of where the source of this information comes from and how to get a definitive list of `android:fontFamily` values, even vendor ones, from your devices. Its just waiting on peer review.

Comment: The definitive list of fonts can be found in [system_fonts.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml) as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24072492/598094)

Comment: Just a quick quesrtion, if I use android:fontFamily in versions prior to (< 4.1) Jelly Bean, will it crash my app or just be ignored?

Comment: @Sandra it will be ignored, so it's safe to use

Comment: Where can I find in the documentation about the available font-families ?

Comment: "sans-serif" (roboto regular) is the default, right?

Comment: How can I use roboto condensed light? Thanks

Comment: @Ricardo Best way is to look at the source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml , which means you want to use "sans-serif-condensed-light"

Comment: What if you use sans-serif-thin on Android 4.1? Will it default to sans-serif-light, sans-serif, or DroidSans?

Comment: since 5.0 you can, post an example in separate answer

Comment: To use Roboto API level 16 is required otherwise, you will get an error.

Comment: So I guess the only font I can't get (without using the RobotoTextView library) is condensed light? right?

Comment: How about Noto family? I cant find a way to make my app use Noto as default font family

Comment: List is also available here: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml

Comment: You can check out this project, for checking font compatibility on TextViews and in WebViews on different platform versions
https://github.com/JeppeLeth/android_font_compat_tester

Comment: sans-serif-medium is not available in my case

Comment: Please, modify your answer - add android:fontFamily="sans-serif-bold" which corresponds to Roboto-bold. Thanks

Comment: Well this is not working for CJK :( Any other ideas?

Comment: And also, android:fontFamily="casual"

Comment: there's a link for a full view of Roboto: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

Comment: This solution no longer works for this font on API level 26: `        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textStyle="normal"`

Answer (score 287):

Starting from **Android-Studio 3.0**  its very easy to change font family

Using support library 26, it will work on devices running Android API version 16 and higher

Create a folder `font` under `res` directory .Download the font which ever you want and paste it inside `font` folder. The structure should be some thing like below

[image: Here]

**Note:** As of Android Support Library 26.0, you must declare both sets of attributes ( android:  and app: ) to ensure your fonts load on devices running 
 Api  26 or lower.

Now you can change font in **layout** using

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="@font/dancing_script"
app:fontFamily="@font/dancing_script"/>
```

To change **Programatically**

```
 Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
   //or to support all versions use
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
 textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

To change font using **styles.xml** create a style

```
 <style name="Regular">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/dancing_script</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/dancing_script</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
 </style>
```

and apply this style to `TextView`

```
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Regular"/>
```

you can also Create your own **font family**

**-** Right-click the font folder and go to **New > Font resource file**. The New Resource File window appears.

**-** Enter the **file name**, and then click **OK**. The new font resource XML opens in the editor.

Write your own font family here , for example

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

this is simply a mapping of a specific fontStyle and fontWeight to the font resource which will be used to render that specific variant. Valid values for fontStyle are normal or italic; and fontWeight conforms to the [CSS font-weight specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-weight-numeric-values)

**1.** To **change** fontfamily in **layout** you can write

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

**2.** To Change **Programmatically**

```
 Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.lobster);
   //or to support all versions use
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.lobster);
 textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

To **change font of entire App** Add these two lines in AppTheme

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
     <item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
  </style>
```

See the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) , [Android Custom Fonts Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/13291/android-custom-fonts-tutorial) For more info

Comment: NB: This currently only works in Android Studio 3.0 Preview. It did not work for me on Android Studio 2.3.3. Hope that saves someone some time!

Comment: How could you get the font from within a fragment since you can't just do `getResources()`?  
  
**EDIT**:  
This line at the end of your answer worked for me:  
  
`Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);`

Comment: Somehow it made font look corrupted in my case, comparing to Caligtraphy. Also fontWeight doesn't do anything

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder it does work , make sure you used both `android:fontWeight` and `app:fontWeight`

Comment: I checked several times. There is no effect.

Comment: Note that `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` must be included in your root element declaration to ensure it doesn't throw the error "Namespace 'app' not bound"

Comment: Right-click main, select 'New', select 'Android Resource File'. In popup window type 'font' for name, select 'Font' from drop-down 'Resource Type' list. Click 'OK'.

Comment: @Manohar How to use it in conjunction with a Textvo

Answer (score 246):

This is the way to set the font programmatically:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

put the font file in your assets folder. In my case I created a subdirectory called fonts.

**EDIT:** If you wonder where is your assets folder see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-assets-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: While this does work, please note that [this can create a memory leak](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904). It can be fixed using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16902532/823952).

Comment: @ScootrNova i get this error when i use your solution. 
Error : Font asset not found gothic.ttf

Comment: How to apply this to whole app?
Right now in example you are applying it only on on textview

Answer (score 111):

I had to parse `/system/etc/fonts.xml` in a recent project. Here are the current font families as of Lollipop:

```
╔════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║    ║ FONT FAMILY                ║ TTF FILE                    ║
╠════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ casual                     ║ ComingSoon.ttf              ║
║  2 ║ cursive                    ║ DancingScript-Regular.ttf   ║
║  3 ║ monospace                  ║ DroidSansMono.ttf           ║
║  4 ║ sans-serif                 ║ Roboto-Regular.ttf          ║
║  5 ║ sans-serif-black           ║ Roboto-Black.ttf            ║
║  6 ║ sans-serif-condensed       ║ RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf ║
║  7 ║ sans-serif-condensed-light ║ RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf   ║
║  8 ║ sans-serif-light           ║ Roboto-Light.ttf            ║
║  9 ║ sans-serif-medium          ║ Roboto-Medium.ttf           ║
║ 10 ║ sans-serif-smallcaps       ║ CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf ║
║ 11 ║ sans-serif-thin            ║ Roboto-Thin.ttf             ║
║ 12 ║ serif                      ║ NotoSerif-Regular.ttf       ║
║ 13 ║ serif-monospace            ║ CutiveMono.ttf              ║
╚════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

---

Here is the parser (based off [FontListParser](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/graphics/java/android/graphics/FontListParser.java)):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Xml;

/**
 * Helper class to get the current font families on an Android device.</p>
 * 
 * Usage:</p> {@code List<SystemFont> fonts = FontListParser.safelyGetSystemFonts();}</p>
 */
public final class FontListParser {

    private static final File FONTS_XML = new File("/system/etc/fonts.xml");

    private static final File SYSTEM_FONTS_XML = new File("/system/etc/system_fonts.xml");

    public static List<SystemFont> getSystemFonts() throws Exception {
        String fontsXml;
        if (FONTS_XML.exists()) {
            fontsXml = FONTS_XML.getAbsolutePath();
        } else if (SYSTEM_FONTS_XML.exists()) {
            fontsXml = SYSTEM_FONTS_XML.getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("fonts.xml does not exist on this system");
        }
        Config parser = parse(new FileInputStream(fontsXml));
        List<SystemFont> fonts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Family family : parser.families) {
            if (family.name != null) {
                Font font = null;
                for (Font f : family.fonts) {
                    font = f;
                    if (f.weight == 400) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                SystemFont systemFont = new SystemFont(family.name, font.fontName);
                if (fonts.contains(systemFont)) {
                    continue;
                }
                fonts.add(new SystemFont(family.name, font.fontName));
            }
        }

        for (Alias alias : parser.aliases) {
            if (alias.name == null || alias.toName == null || alias.weight == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (Family family : parser.families) {
                if (family.name == null || !family.name.equals(alias.toName)) {
                    continue;
                }
                for (Font font : family.fonts) {
                    if (font.weight == alias.weight) {
                        fonts.add(new SystemFont(alias.name, font.fontName));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (fonts.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception("No system fonts found.");
        }

        Collections.sort(fonts, new Comparator<SystemFont>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(SystemFont font1, SystemFont font2) {
                return font1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(font2.name);
            }

        });

        return fonts;
    }

    public static List<SystemFont> safelyGetSystemFonts() {
        try {
            return getSystemFonts();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String[][] defaultSystemFonts = {
                    {
                            "cursive", "DancingScript-Regular.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "monospace", "DroidSansMono.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif", "Roboto-Regular.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif-light", "Roboto-Light.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif-medium", "Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif-black", "Roboto-Black.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif-condensed", "RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "sans-serif-thin", "Roboto-Thin.ttf"
                    }, {
                            "serif", "NotoSerif-Regular.ttf"
                    }
            };
            List<SystemFont> fonts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String[] names : defaultSystemFonts) {
                File file = new File("/system/fonts", names[1]);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    fonts.add(new SystemFont(names[0], file.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
            return fonts;
        }
    }

    /* Parse fallback list (no names) */
    public static Config parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            parser.nextTag();
            return readFamilies(parser);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private static Alias readAlias(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Alias alias = new Alias();
        alias.name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
        alias.toName = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "to");
        String weightStr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "weight");
        if (weightStr == null) {
            alias.weight = 0;
        } else {
            alias.weight = Integer.parseInt(weightStr);
        }
        skip(parser); // alias tag is empty, ignore any contents and consume end tag
        return alias;
    }

    private static Config readFamilies(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        Config config = new Config();
        parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "familyset");
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            if (parser.getName().equals("family")) {
                config.families.add(readFamily(parser));
            } else if (parser.getName().equals("alias")) {
                config.aliases.add(readAlias(parser));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return config;
    }

    private static Family readFamily(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,
            IOException {
        String name = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
        String lang = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "lang");
        String variant = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "variant");
        List<Font> fonts = new ArrayList<Font>();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String tag = parser.getName();
            if (tag.equals("font")) {
                String weightStr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "weight");
                int weight = weightStr == null ? 400 : Integer.parseInt(weightStr);
                boolean isItalic = "italic".equals(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "style"));
                String filename = parser.nextText();
                String fullFilename = "/system/fonts/" + filename;
                fonts.add(new Font(fullFilename, weight, isItalic));
            } else {
                skip(parser);
            }
        }
        return new Family(name, fonts, lang, variant);
    }

    private static void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth > 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private FontListParser() {

    }

    public static class Alias {

        public String name;

        public String toName;

        public int weight;
    }

    public static class Config {

        public List<Alias> aliases;

        public List<Family> families;

        Config() {
            families = new ArrayList<Family>();
            aliases = new ArrayList<Alias>();
        }

    }

    public static class Family {

        public List<Font> fonts;

        public String lang;

        public String name;

        public String variant;

        public Family(String name, List<Font> fonts, String lang, String variant) {
            this.name = name;
            this.fonts = fonts;
            this.lang = lang;
            this.variant = variant;
        }

    }

    public static class Font {

        public String fontName;

        public boolean isItalic;

        public int weight;

        Font(String fontName, int weight, boolean isItalic) {
            this.fontName = fontName;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.isItalic = isItalic;
        }

    }

    public static class SystemFont {

        public String name;

        public String path;

        public SystemFont(String name, String path) {
            this.name = name;
            this.path = path;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Feel free to use the above class in your project. For example, you could give your users a selection of font families and set the typeface based on their preference.

A small incomplete example:

```
final List<FontListParser.SystemFont> fonts = FontListParser.safelyGetSystemFonts();
String[] items = new String[fonts.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < fonts.size(); i++) {
    items[i] = fonts.get(i).name;
}

new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        FontListParser.SystemFont selectedFont = fonts.get(which);
        // TODO: do something with the font
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedFont.path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}).show();
```

Comment: Do you know perhaps which version of Android added which font?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I don't. You could probably find out by viewing the changes here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml

Comment: @JaredRummler, forgive my ignorance. Why/What is weight==400 ?

Comment: @Samuel I haven't looked at this code in a while, but 400 font weight is used for "normal" or "regular" fonts. Example, Roboto-Regular has a weight of 400.

Comment: Does this require root or something? I ran this code on the Android emulator (version 8.1), and when I called `getSystemFonts()`, I got an exception `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: END_TAG expected (position:START_TAG (empty) <axis tag='wdth' stylevalue='100.0'>@219:51 in java.io.InputStreamReader@f001fb3) `

Comment: Can anyone explain how each TTF file was mapped as the default for each font family? For example, for sans-serif, why is it that Roboto-Regular was the TTF file used? I see many files listed in this font family. Why was this particular one chosen over the others?

Comment: Okay, I see that you used a weight of 400 as a threshold to determine the default font. Why 400 though?

Answer (score 52):

Android doesn't allow you to set custom fonts from the XML layout. Instead, you must bundle the specific font file in your app's assets folder, and set it programmatically. Something like:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Note that you can only run this code after setContentView() has been called. Also, only some fonts are supported by Android, and should be in a `.ttf (TrueType)` or `.otf (OpenType)` format. Even then, some fonts may not work.

[This](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Chantelli-Antiqua) is a font that definitely works on Android, and you can use this to confirm that your code is working in case your font file isn't supported by Android.

Android O Update: This is now possible with [XML in Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html), based on Roger's comment.

Comment: "Android doesn't allow you to set custom fonts from the XML layout." This has been changed in Android O, which allows you to create customized font family and apply them in XML: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

Answer (score 33):

**Kotlin Code - Textview to set custom font from Resource Folder**

Set custom font from *res -> font -> avenir_next_regular.ttf*

```
textView!!.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context!!, R.font.avenir_next_regular)
```

Answer (score 31):

If you want it programatically, you could use

```
label.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

Where `SANS_SERIF` you can use:

- `DEFAULT`
- `DEFAULT_BOLD`
- `MONOSPACE`
- `SANS_SERIF`
- `SERIF`

And where `ITALIC` you can use:

- `BOLD`
- `BOLD_ITALIC`
- `ITALIC`
- `NORMAL`

All is stated [on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html)

Answer (score 31):

To set Roboto programmatically:

```
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-thin", Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Answer (score 27):

It's the same as `android:typeface`.

built-in fonts are:

- normal
- sans
- serif
- monospace

See [android:typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:typeface).

Comment: I don't think it is the same thing, but it does appear that we can't use both. It seems that there are now no less than three different attributes mapped to ``setTypeface()``. Namely ``fontFamily``, ``typeface`` and ``textStyle``. But I can't for the life of me figure out how these are precisely combined to resolve a concrete Typeface instance. Has anyone figured this out? Google's documentation is less than helpful...

Answer (score 25):

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

set easily font to any `textview` from `res`>font directory programmatically

Answer (score 23):

One simple way is by adding the desired **font** in the project.

Go to **File->New->New Resource Directory**
Select ***font***

This will create a new directory, **font**, in your resources.

Download your **font (.ttf)**. I use https://fonts.google.com for the same

Add that to your **fonts** folder then use them in the XML or programmatically.

XML -

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="@font/your_font"/>
```

Programatically -

```
 Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.your_font);
 textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Better use `ResourcesCompat.getFont` method

Answer (score 21):

I think I am too late but maybe this solution helpful for others. For using a custom font place your font file in your font directory.

```
textView.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.lato));
```

Answer (score 15):

I am using the excellent library [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) by Chris Jenx designed to allow you to use custom fonts in your android application. Give it a try!

Comment: yep, but for example i want to use it functionanl, but didn t want to implement all library;)

Answer (score 12):

What you want is not possible. You must need to set `TypeFace` in your Code.

In `XML` what you can do is

```
android:typeface="sans" | "serif" | "monospace"
```

other then this you can not play much with the Fonts in XML. :)

For `Arial` you need to set type face in your code.

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to manage the fonts would be to declare them via resources, as such:

```
<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<!--added on API 16 (JB - 4.1)-->
<!--++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<!--the default font-->
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_regular">sans-serif</string>
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_light">sans-serif-light</string>
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_condensed">sans-serif-condensed</string>

<!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<!--added on API 17 (JBMR1 - 4.2)-->
<!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_thin">sans-serif-thin</string>

<!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<!--added on Lollipop (LL- 5.0)-->
<!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++-->
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_medium">sans-serif-medium</string>
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_black">sans-serif-black</string>
<string name="fontFamily__roboto_condensed_light">sans-serif-condensed-light</string>
```

This is based on the source code [**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml) and [**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml)

Comment: Where to declare them?

Comment: @AZ_ Just like many resource files, you can put it in any XML file you wish, inside the "res/values/" folder . For example, put it in "res/values/fonts.xml" . And, to use it, do simply like this for example :  android:fontFamily="string/fontFamily__roboto_regular"

Comment: Thanks, I am using this https://github.com/norbsoft/android-typeface-helper and it's really helpful

Comment: ok, the library is probably for doing it programmatically. here it's for XML

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Android Studio 3.5+, Changing the font is super simple. Select the text widget on the Design view and check the font family on Attribute Window. The value dropdown contains all the available fonts from which you can select one. If you are looking for Google Fonts, Click the More Fonts option.

**Attribute Window**
[image: Attribute Window]

**Google Fonts**
[image: Google Fonts]

Comment: This answer should be way more top in 2020

Answer (score 9):

Dynamically you can set the fontfamily similar to android:fontFamily in xml by using this,

```
For Custom font:

 TextView tv = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.select_item_title));
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mycustomfont.ttf"); 
 tv.setTypeface(face);

For Default font:

 tv.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium",Typeface.NORMAL));
```

These are the list of ***default font*** family used, use any of this by replacing the double quotation string **"sans-serif-medium"**

```
FONT FAMILY                    TTF FILE                    

1  casual                      ComingSoon.ttf              
2  cursive                     DancingScript-Regular.ttf   
3  monospace                   DroidSansMono.ttf           
4  sans-serif                  Roboto-Regular.ttf          
5  sans-serif-black            Roboto-Black.ttf            
6  sans-serif-condensed        RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf 
7  sans-serif-condensed-light  RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf   
8  sans-serif-light            Roboto-Light.ttf            
9  sans-serif-medium           Roboto-Medium.ttf           
10  sans-serif-smallcaps       CarroisGothicSC-Regular.ttf 
11  sans-serif-thin            Roboto-Thin.ttf             
12  serif                      NotoSerif-Regular.ttf       
13  serif-monospace            CutiveMono.ttf
```

"mycustomfont.ttf" is the ttf file. ***Path*** will be in *src/assets/fonts/mycustomfont.ttf* , you can refer more about default font in this [Default font family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535475/what-is-the-default-font-family-in-android#39536066)

Answer (score 8):

You can also do this by adding a font folder under the res directory like below.

[image]

Then, selecting Font as the resource type.
[image]

You can find avaliable fonts from https://www.1001fonts.com/, and then extracting the TTF files to this font directory.

[image]

Finally, just change the XML file that contains your textview by adding android:fontFamily:"@font/urfontfilename"

[image]

Comment: very nice, thank you for this. idk why others have more stars but yours is confirmed to work with material design text view, you must use `app:fontFamily=` however, everything else is the same.

Comment: YOu saved my life, I had just created a folder named font and it did not work. Anyway I used your way and it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

With some trial and error I learned the following.

Within the *.xml you can combine the stock fonts with the following functions, not only with typeface:

```
 android:fontFamily="serif" 
 android:textStyle="italic"
```

With this two styles, there was no need to use typeface in any other case. The range of combinations is much more bigger with fontfamily&textStyle.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Tahoma.ttf");
textview .setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 5):

The valid value of android:fontFamily is defined in /system/etc/system_fonts.xml(4.x) or /system/etc/fonts.xml(5.x). But Device Manufacturer might modify it, so the actual font used by setting fontFamily value depends on the above-mentioned file of the specified device.

In AOSP, the Arial font is valid but must be defined using "arial" not "Arial", for example **android:fontFamily="arial"**. Have a qucik look at Kitkat's system_fonts.xml

```
    <family>
    <nameset>
        <name>sans-serif</name>
        <name>arial</name>
        <name>helvetica</name>
        <name>tahoma</name>
        <name>verdana</name>
    </nameset>
    <fileset>
        <file>Roboto-Regular.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Bold.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-Italic.ttf</file>
        <file>Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</file>
    </fileset>
</family>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

There are three relevant xml-attributes for defining a "font" in layout--**android:fontFamily**, **android:typeface** and **android:textStyle**. The combination of "fontFamily" and "textStyle" or "typeface" and "textStyle" can be used to change the appearance of font in text, so does used alone. Code snippet in **TextView.java** like this:

```
    private void setTypefaceFromAttrs(String familyName, int typefaceIndex, int styleIndex) {
    Typeface tf = null;
    if (familyName != null) {
        tf = Typeface.create(familyName, styleIndex);
        if (tf != null) {
            setTypeface(tf);
            return;
        }
    }
    switch (typefaceIndex) {
        case SANS:
            tf = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
            break;

        case SERIF:
            tf = Typeface.SERIF;
            break;

        case MONOSPACE:
            tf = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
            break;
    }
    setTypeface(tf, styleIndex);
}


    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    if (style > 0) {
        if (tf == null) {
            tf = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(style);
        } else {
            tf = Typeface.create(tf, style);
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
        // now compute what (if any) algorithmic styling is needed
        int typefaceStyle = tf != null ? tf.getStyle() : 0;
        int need = style & ~typefaceStyle;
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText((need & Typeface.BOLD) != 0);
        mTextPaint.setTextSkewX((need & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0 ? -0.25f : 0);
    } else {
        mTextPaint.setFakeBoldText(false);
        mTextPaint.setTextSkewX(0);
        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

From the code We can see:

1. if "fontFamily" is set, then the "typeface" will be ignored.
2. "typeface" has standard and limited valid values. In fact, the values are "normal" "sans" "serif" and "monospace", they can be found in system_fonts.xml(4.x) or fonts.xml(5.x). Actually both "normal" and "sans" are the default font of system.
3. "fontFamily" can be used to set all fonts of build-in fonts, while "typeface"  only provide the typical fonts of "sans-serif" "serif" and "monospace"(the three main category of font type in the world).
4. When only set "textStyle", We actually set the default font and the specified style. The effective value are "normal" "bold" "italic" and "bold | italic".

Answer (score 5):

To set the font by program, write...

```
 TextView tv7 = new TextView(this);
 tv7.setText(" TIME ");    
 tv7.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed",Typeface.BOLD));
 tv7.setTextSize(12);
 tbrow.addView(tv7);
```

The name "sans-serif-condensed" is referenced from the fonts.xml file which should be created in-app--> res--> values folder and it holds the fonts in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="font_family_light">sans-serif-light</string>
    <string name="font_family_medium">sans-serif-medium</string>
    <string name="font_family_regular">sans-serif</string>
    <string name="font_family_condensed">sans-serif-condensed</string>
    <string name="font_family_black">sans-serif-black</string>
    <string name="font_family_thin">sans-serif-thin</string>
</resources>
```

Hope this is clear!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an **easier wa**y that can work in some cases. The principle is to add a not visible TextVview in your xml layout and to **get its typeFace** in the java code.

The layout in the xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:text="The classic bread is made of flour hot and salty. The classic bread is made of flour hot and salty. The classic bread is made of flour hot and salty."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"/>
```

And the java code:

```
myText.setTypeface(textViewSelectedDescription.getTypeface());
```

It has worked for me (within a TextSwitcher for example).

Answer (score 3):

```
<string name="font_family_display_4_material">sans-serif-light</string>
<string name="font_family_display_3_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_display_2_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_display_1_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_headline_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_title_material">sans-serif-medium</string>
<string name="font_family_subhead_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_menu_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_body_2_material">sans-serif-medium</string>
<string name="font_family_body_1_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_caption_material">sans-serif</string>
<string name="font_family_button_material">sans-serif-medium</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a TextView in so many places with the same font family, extend the TextView class and set your font like this:-

```
public class ProximaNovaTextView extends TextView {
    public ProximaNovaTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }
    public ProximaNovaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        applyCustomFont(context);
    }
    public ProximaNovaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       applyCustomFont(context);
    } 
    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface customFont = FontCache.getTypeface("proximanova_regular.otf", context);
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }
}
```

And then use this custom class in XML for the TextView like this:-

```
<com.myapp.customview.ProximaNovaTextView
android:id="@+id/feed_list_item_name_tv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="14sp"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom FontFamily like this:

`/res/font/usual.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="200"
        android:font="@font/usual_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="200"
        app:font="@font/usual_regular" />

    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="200"
        android:font="@font/usual_regular_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="200"
        app:font="@font/usual_regular_italic" />

    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="600"
        android:font="@font/usual_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/usual_bold" />

    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="600"
        android:font="@font/usual_bold_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/usual_bold_italic" />
</font-family>
```

Now you can do

```
android:fontFamily="@font/usual"
```

Assuming your other `font` resources are there as well, with lowercase letters and `_`s.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to mention that the hell with the fonts inside Android is about to end, because this year on Google IO we finally got this -> https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html

Now there is a new resource type a **font** and you can place all your application fonts inside res/fonts folder and access then with R.font.my_custom_font, just like you can access **string** res values, **drawable** res values etc. You have even chance to create **font-face** xml file, which is gonna be set of your custom fonts (about italic, bold and underline attr).

Read the link above for more info. Let's see the support.

Comment: Sadly this still does not work with IntelliJ (though working like a charm on Android Studio 3.0+).

Comment: Yes, but user `Redman`'s answer above is still very much so a necessary part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

For android-studio 3 and above you can use this style and then all `textView` font changes in-app.

create this style in your `style.xml` :

```
<!--OverRide all textView font-->
<style name="defaultTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your_custom_font</item>
</style>
```

Then use it in your theme :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/defaultTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also change standard fonts with `setTextAppearance` (requires API 16), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36301508/2914140:

```
<style name="styleA">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="styleB">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorTertiary</item>
</style>


if(condition){
    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, R.style.styleA);
} else {
    TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView,R.style.styleB);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The new font resource allows to directly set `font` using

```
android:fontFamily="@font/my_font_in_font_folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

You set style in `res/layout/value/style.xml` like that:

```
<style name="boldText">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

and to use this style in `main.xml` file use:

```
style="@style/boldText"
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way **to add the font programatically to a TextView** is to, first, add the font file in your Assets folder in the project. For example your font path is looking like this: `assets/fonts/my_font.otf`

And add it to a TextView as:

Kotlin

```
val font_path = "fonts/my_font.otf"  

myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(MyApplication.getInstance().assets, font_path)

textView.typeface = myTypeface
```

Java

```
String font_path = "fonts/my_font.otf";
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(MyApplication.getInstance().assets, font_path)
textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library available for this

```
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
```

Comment: This library isu used to change font of all views in entire application. This is not applicable for adapter views such as list view. For that we need to add code in each adapter specifically

Answer (score 1):

Probably my comment will be useful for somebody: I was trying to realize why `app:fontFamily="@font/my_font"`doesn't work and after wasting some time found that the working solution is `android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"`

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/data/fonts/fonts.xml) you can see all the available font-family values and their corresponding font file names(This file is used in android 5.0+). On a mobile device, you can find it in:

```
/system/etc/fonts.xml (for 5.0+)
```

(For android 4.4 and below using [this](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml) version, but I think that `fonts.xml` has a more clear format and is easy to understand.)

For example,

```
    <!-- first font is default -->
20    <family name="sans-serif">
21        <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
22        <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
23        <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
24        <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
25        <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
26        <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
27        <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
28        <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
29        <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
30        <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
31        <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
32        <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
33    </family>
```

The name attribute `name="sans-serif"` of `family` tag defined the value you can use in android:fontFamily.

The `font` tag defines the corresponded font files.

In this case, you can ignore the source under `<!-- fallback fonts -->`, it's used for fonts' fallback logic.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Letter Press lib](https://github.com/Pixplicity/letterpress) for my NonTextView stuff like Buttons and [kianoni fontloader lib](https://github.com/Kianoni/android-fontloading-textview) for my TextViews cause of usage of style in this lib is easier than Letter Press for me and I got ideal feedback with that.
this is great for those who want to use a custom font except Roboto Font.
so it was my experience with font libs.
for those who want to use a custom class to change the font, I highly recommended creating this class with this snippet

```
public class TypefaceSpan extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    /** An <code>LruCache</code> for previously loaded typefaces. */
    private static LruCache<String, Typeface> sTypefaceCache =
            new LruCache<String, Typeface>(12);

    private Typeface mTypeface;

    /**
     * Load the {@link android.graphics.Typeface} and apply to a {@link android.text.Spannable}.
     */
    public TypefaceSpan(Context context, String typefaceName) {
        mTypeface = sTypefaceCache.get(typefaceName);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getApplicationContext()
                    .getAssets(), String.format("fonts/%s", typefaceName));

            // Cache the loaded Typeface
            sTypefaceCache.put(typefaceName, mTypeface);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint p) {
        p.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        p.setFlags(p.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setTypeface(mTypeface);

        // Note: This flag is required for proper typeface rendering
        tp.setFlags(tp.getFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    }
}
```

And use class like this :

```
AppData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
TextView bannertv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBanner);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getResources().getString(R.string.enterkey));
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, AppData.getString("font-Bold",null)), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    bannertv.setText(s);
```

maybe this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easy way by using following library

https://github.com/sunnag7/FontStyler

```
<com.sunnag.fontstyler.FontStylerView
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:text="@string/about_us"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingTop="8dp"
              app:fontName="Lato-Bold"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:id="@+id/textView64" />
```

its light weight and easy to implement, just copy your fonts in asset folder and use name in xml.

Answer (score 0):

try these simple steps.
1. create font folder in res folder.
2. copy and paste .ttf file into font folder.
3. Now give the path in xml like below.

```
 android:fontFamily="@font/frutiger"
```

or what ever your file name is.
Thats it happy code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_regular"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_regular"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_italic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="400" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_medium"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_medium"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="500" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_medium_italic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="500"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_medium_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="500" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_bold"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_bold"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="600" />

    <font
        android:font="@font/google_sans_bold_italic"
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="600"
        app:font="@font/google_sans_bold_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:fontWeight="600" />

</font-family>
```