# Android Monospace fonts aren't fixed width

Tags: android, view, ondraw, typeface, monospace

I'm writing a custom View for a timer, but I can't get  a properly fixed-width font for the numbers in the middle. Here's the relevant code (from two different methods):

```
mTextPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.NORMAL));

// Get rectangle that is the size of the text
mTextPaint.getTextBounds(
        getTimeText(),
        0,
        getTimeText().length(),
        mTextBounds);

// X and Y coordinates of text
float mTextPosX = (width / 2) - (mTextBounds.width() / 2);
float mTextPosY = (height / 2) + (mTextBounds.height() / 2);

// Draw text
canvas.drawText(
        getTimeText(),
        mTextPosX,
        mTextPosY,
        mTextPaint);
```

This seems to work fine, but whenever one of the numbers changes to a 1, that 1 takes up less space and the whole chunk of text moves over a bit. This obviously should not be happening, since I'm using a monospace font. Can anyone shed some light on how I might fix this?

Comment: Hey could you fix it? Im on the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. A way to fix it is by using an external font in which "1" behaves as expected. A website with many fonts to try is this one: http://www.fontcubes.com/   . A related discussion on how to use external fonts in Android is here: [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)  .