# How change fontfamily in 4.0.3?

Tags: java, android, xml

From android 4.1 / 4.2, the following Roboto font families are available:

```
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
 android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
```

But I need something like that for version 4.0.3. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Android doesn't allow you to set custom fonts from the XML layout. Instead, you must bundle the specific font file in your app's assets folder, and set it programmatically. Something like:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Note that you can only run this code after setContentView() has been called. Also, only some fonts are supported by Android, and should be in a .ttf (TrueType) or .otf (OpenType) format. Even then, some fonts may not work.

**EDIT**

[image]

And [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto) you can download `.ttf` files.

Comment: It is in your project's root if not then create one.

Answer (score 2):

As you say before V4.2 `sans-serif-thin` is not available for devices on versions below that.

But you can put a font file with your apk by putting a `.ttf` or `.otf` file into your `/assets` folder and using this code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

here is the full example: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

You can also get the `sans-serif-thin` font here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto

Answer (score 0):

install/keep font in asset folder and asign it to the text view programatically.

```
Typeface mDesiredFace= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"sans-serif.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(mDesiredFace);
```