# Supporting custom text weight in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to support more than standard three available text weights in Android. I need to have five: ExtraLight, Light, Normal, Medium and Bold.
I saw this question: [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android), but it related to family rather than weight.

If there is no in-build support, maybe any external resources or libraries are available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not aware of how a library could add support for your font without including it, I would advise you to create your own implementation of TextView to handle that, it can be done quite quickly, if you only need it for TextView (you would need to implement your own EditText as well if you need that widget).

You can start by looking at the [RobotoTextView library](https://github.com/johnkil/Android-RobotoTextView) which allows for the RobotoTextView widgets to be used in code as well as directly in xml, using attributes.

Comment: The design idea was to have different weights for any font on users phone, but I think this will be suitable. Thanks a lot for your help