# Android Design Guide lines? (font weights)

Tags: android, typography

According to the [Android Typography Design Guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html), "The current TextView framework offers Roboto in thin, light, regular and bold weights". However, as far as I can tell, all that I can use as a developer is regular and bold. Am I missing something, or is that guide lying through its virtual teeth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish this was documented somewhere - I've got designers at my throat trying to use font styles I can't find in the OS...

Comment: In the worst case you can always just include the fonts in the assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, the docs don't lie. Those guys know what they are writing ;)

These font types are only available starting from Jellybean 4.1 and can be accessed as described here:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts

Comment: I see some more font options there than were mentioned in other documentation, but what about Roboto Medium? Is that the same as Roboto Light Bold, maybe?