# How to set Roboto Font in Material Design (Best Practice)

Tags: android, material-design

I want to set Roboto font in Material Design. 
Shall I need to add font in Asset Folder as I used to do previously.
I know how to set custom font to any View but want to use for Material Design.
My application will be used on Android 3.0 and onward.

I have been using following to use custom fonts

```
public static Typeface getTypeFace() {
    if (fromAsset == null) {
        fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
    }
    return fromAsset;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since your application will be used on Android 3.0 you should keep your fonts in the Asset folder for backward compatibility otherwise for Android 4.1.+ you can simply do this

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/3144836) for more details.

Comment: It means for backward compatibility I have to manually detect and then take decision?

Comment: @ForGuru Not really. Please use styles and keep the styles inside `values-v16` folder