# How does fonts.xml works in android Lollipop?

Tags: android, fonts, android-5.0-lollipop, fallback, android-fonts

[fonts.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml)

```
<family name="sans-serif">
    <font weight="100" style="normal">Roboto-Thin.ttf</font>
    <font weight="100" style="italic">Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="300" style="normal">Roboto-Light.ttf</font>
    <font weight="300" style="italic">Roboto-LightItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="400" style="normal">Roboto-Regular.ttf</font>
    <font weight="400" style="italic">Roboto-Italic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="500" style="normal">Roboto-Medium.ttf</font>
    <font weight="500" style="italic">Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="900" style="normal">Roboto-Black.ttf</font>
    <font weight="900" style="italic">Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf</font>
    <font weight="700" style="normal">Roboto-Bold.ttf</font>
    <font weight="700" style="italic">Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf</font>
</family>

<!-- Note that aliases must come after the fonts they reference. -->
<alias name="sans-serif-thin" to="sans-serif" weight="100" />
<alias name="sans-serif-light" to="sans-serif" weight="300" />
<alias name="sans-serif-medium" to="sans-serif" weight="500" />
<alias name="sans-serif-black" to="sans-serif" weight="900" />
<alias name="arial" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="helvetica" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="tahoma" to="sans-serif" />
<alias name="verdana" to="sans-serif" />
```

How these mappings work? is the hypen in family name e.g. "sans-serif-thin" is intentional? Is there any documentation available for understanding fonts.xml behaviour?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android has a lot of the answer your looking for

Comment: Thank you @DwightSpencer. I would like to know more about how minikin source code accesses fonts.xml and how exactly it processes?. It would be helpful if you have any information to share on the same line.

Comment: Then I suggest reviewing the android.widget.TextView source code at https://source.android.com/source/index.html as that is going to be best way to learn.

Comment: can we add two different mappings for the same family name?
e.g. 
if case 1 happens
map arial to sans-serif
else
map arial to serif


or another possibility is

only if case 3 happens

map arial to sans-serif

Comment: I doubt that but it would be better if you asked that as a new question. I would suggest to try under [Android:SE](http://android.stackexchange.com) for better results.