# I want change the textSize but I don't want change thickness,how can I do?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, thickness

I used the textview to display the temperature, it should be like this

[image]

when I change the textSize, it display like this

[image]

I just want change the size of the textview, but I don't want it to be more thicker,how should I do with this problem?

Comment: paste you xml (text view) for more information

Comment: you may use custom font for this effect

Comment: Looks like Roboto Thin. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android

Comment: Thanks, Mike, you are right. I used android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin",it works.

Answer (score 0):

add this to you textView

```
android:fontFamily="Roboto-Thin"
```

Comment: I tried ndroid:fontFamily="Roboto-Thin" ,it doesn't work ,I used android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin" ,it works.Thank anyway