# Android Studio set fontfamily via layout editor

Tags: android-layout, android-fonts

currently I'm setting up fonts for runtime with

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/customFont.otf");
    this.customTxtView.setTypeface(customFont);
}
```

But that font doesn't reflect in the Layout Editor in Android Studio. I've tried setting `android:typeface` as well as `android:fontFamily` using the same values as I'm using in the code with no avail.

Is it possible to have the Layout Builder reflect custom font changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

> From android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0, the following
>   [Roboto](http://robotofont.com/) font families are available:
>
> ```
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
> android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> in combination with
>
> ```
> android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
> ```
>
> this 14 variants are possible:
>
> - Roboto regular
> - Roboto italic
> - Roboto bold
> - Roboto bold italic
> - Roboto-Light
> - Roboto-Light italic
> - Roboto-Thin
> - Roboto-Thin italic
> - Roboto-Condensed
> - Roboto-Condensed italic
> - Roboto-Condensed bold
> - Roboto-Condensed bold italic
> - Roboto-Medium
> - Roboto-Medium italic

NOTE: There's also `robotium-thin` typespace.

---

But as I see you want to use your custom font, so you would find also there that:

> Android doesn't allow you to set custom fonts from the XML layout.
>   Instead, you must bundle the specific font file in your app's assets
>   folder, and set it programmatically. Something like:
>
> ```
> TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
> Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
> textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
> ```
>
> Note that you can only run this code after setContentView() has been
>   called. Also, only some fonts are supported by Android, and should be
>   in a `.ttf (TrueType)` or `.otf (OpenType)` format. Even then, some
>   fonts may not work.
>
> [This](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Chantelli-Antiqua) is a font that definitely works on Android, and you can use
>   this to confirm that your code is working in case your font file isn't
>   supported by Android.

Please free to say, if this post doesn't help you

Comment: This just validates that it's not yet possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should see `textAppearance` property on the right when a `TextView` is selected. You can either select a predefined text appearance or expand the group and specify the font family only.

[image: text appearance settings in Layout Editor]