# how can I customize this listview just a little?

Tags: android, listview

I am absolute beginner.

I have a simple listview  which I don't know how its work and the only view code i fount of it is :

```
  String[] from = new String[]{ TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.ViewTitleNotes };
```

thats it, I want to customize this listview a little like change the font or set a background for listview page, but i cant !
if I change the background of page, every single listview item will adopt that image and every single listview item height will fill entire page !
that "R.id.ViewTitleNotes" doesn't have any code like this : "TextView ViewTitleNotes = (textView) findViewById(R.id.ViewTitleNotes);"

I don't Know how its work !

here is a Screenshot of this listview: that small selection is the textview i want to change the font of it

[image: that small selection is the textview i want to change the font of it]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this tutorial to understand how the listview works and how to customize the layout - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSZLqBWKTHw

Comment: take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for change font of textView take a look at :
[How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

for setting image in background of listview look at this link:
http://www.android-examples.com/set-drawable-image-as-listview-background-in-android/

and link bellow for more complicated listView:
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

also it is recommended to use recyclerview instead of listView.
for recyclerview , link bellow :
https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-complex-lists-with-the-android-recyclerview/

http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example

Comment: doesn't work. when I want to use setTypeface, exactly on setTypeface line it gives nullpoinexeption error...  (Dadash kheilii mokhlesima, parcham balast !)

Comment: I don't wanna use RecyclerView !

Comment: please give us your xml and source code if it is possible.

Comment: I cant, when i copy the code here, the page give me an error and says code is not formated.