# How create TextView programatically with this specifics Attributes?

Tags: java, android, textview, programmatically-created

I'm currently creating TextView like that:

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
    {
        pairs[l] = new TextView(context);
        pairs[l].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
        pairs[l].setLayoutParams(lp);
        pairs[l].setId(l);
        pairs[l].setText("asd");
        myLayout.addView(pairs[l]);
    }
```

Now I want set this attribute to all of this TextView:

- **FontFamily: cursive**
- SetTextSize not sp but dp (RESOLVED)
- SetGravity: central_horizontal (RESOLVED)

I couldn't find a way for set those attribute when I create a TextView programatically, How can I do that?

Comment: use layout params to adjust those

Comment: I did it for adjust gravity and the height (wrap_content), but How about last two attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the font family of a TextView use [setTypeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface))

for instance:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.create("cursive", Typeface.NORMAL);
for(int l=0; l<4; l++)
{
    pairs[l] = new TextView(context);
    pairs[l].setTypeface(tf);
    ...
}
```

Also, this may interest: [How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Text size in dp can be set using `setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <float>)` - see documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int, float)).

As for the font family, I'm afraid I don't know - hopefully someone else can help you with this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font using Typeface object.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
       "fonts/filename.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Put the font in the assets folder of your project.

Comment: Can't use this because i don't have the file .TFF of "Cursive"