# I can't find sans-serif-medium in font family Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-typeface

I am following the Typography guide and this link

[How to change fontFamily of TextView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

It says sans-serif-medium is available on Android 4.1 / 4.2 / 5.0.

But when I try to find these font types, I can't seem to find the suggestion. Why??

[image]

Do i have to download ttf files for this font??

My complied SDK is 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this to use Sans Serif font.

In your styles.xml files, define style for font

```
<style name="roboto_regular_textview" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
    </style>

    <style name="roboto_medium_textview" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

    <style name="roboto_light_textview" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

And in layout.xml file

```
<TextView
                style="@style/roboto_regular_textview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: thank you, it seems sans-serif-medium to be working but just doesn't show up. No idea why....