# How to change font-family of toolbar title?

Tags: android

I want to change font-family of my toolbar title to `sans-serif-smallcaps`. How do I do it?

My `AppTheme` has parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Edit: Toolbar XML:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: If you are using `Toolbar` then my answer is the best answer I can guarantee of that. Because even I am using `Toolbar`, just provide title using `toolbar.getTitle()`. I don't know why it has been marked down as negative, but I am sure it will help you.

Comment: If you want to get preloaded list of fonts have a look at this solution, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29533686/842607 It also describes which typeface using which ttf file. And also they have given demo of how to use `Reflection` in it

Comment: @RandomyzeEverything See my answer below and also see the attached image for output.

Answer (score 20):

My **Layout** Page:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Go to Your **styles.xml**  then add your font (This is works in Android Studio 3.0)

```
 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/handlee_regular</item>
/// change your font
</style>
```

Comment: my main theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar I tried to change parent of toolbar style to ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Ligh as there is no overlay with NoActionBar but the font is never changed. Do you know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: finally worked changing from app:popupTheme to android:theme

Comment: you just set `TextAppearance` instead of the whole `popupTheme`

Answer (score 2):

**# To Use default Android Font-Family:**

In your `Toolbar` XML, add a child `TextView` to show the `Title`. Set android font-family to `TextView` using attribute `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"`

**Toolbar:**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/oolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stack Overflow"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**# To Use External Font:**

1. Put external font file into location: `.../app/src/main/assets/fonts/YOUR_CUSTOM_FONT.ttf`
2. Add below codes in your `Activity` to set `custom font` to `Toolbar` title.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        // Custom title
        TextView textCustomTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_title);

        // Custom font
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Exo2-BoldItalic.ttf");

        // Set
        textCustomTitle.setTypeface(customFont);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    .......
    ..............
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: I want to use a font which is built in, because in my other XMLs, I just use `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"`, how do I use it in your code?

Comment: @RandomyzeEverything see my updated answer "To Use default Android Font-Family". Hope this will work for you.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it does not work with collapsing toolbar. An addition toolbar title is just pinned to the top.

Answer (score 2):

For material toolbar, Add a style in your themes.xml like below:

```
  <style name="toolbar_text">

        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_name</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>

    </style>
```

then in your Material toolbar, add it to
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbar_text"

like below

```
   <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar

        ...

        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/toolbar_text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.

```
mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            View view = mToolbar.getChildAt(0);
            if (view != null && view instanceof TextView) {
                TextView title = (TextView) view;
                AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr, "ttf.ttf");//Font file in /assets
                title.setTypeface(tf);
                mToolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your font file (.ttf) in assets folder and write following code in Activity class.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "sansSmallCaps.ttf");

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);

text.setTypeface(font);
```

**Update**

You are right in getting the textview with getChildAt(0)..but I don't know why the font didn't apply to title. but my guess is you need to set font before  setting `setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);`

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
myToolbar.setTitle("xyz");
TextView tv=(TextView) myToolbar.getChildAt(0);
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Comment: Why do I need to put my font file in assets folder? In my other XMLs, I just use `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"` so isn't it kind of inbuilt? And also can I get `TextView` by using `TextView textView = (TextView) toolbar.getChildAt(0)`?

Comment: I thought u have .ttf file.so you can directly use it in the same way to toolbar title in xml..didn't that work?

Comment: @RandomyzeEverything Check my code, in that you can use this line `toolbarTitle.setSpan(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, 0 , toolbarTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);` and remove `CustomTypefaceSpace` class from it

Comment: @sravs Added my XML

Comment: @JimitPatel A perfect answer. But why did you posted it as a comment?  You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `SpannableString` object and pass the font path from asset. Check the working below

```
SpannableString toolbarTitle = new SpannableString(getActionBar().getTitle());
        String toolbarFont = getResources().getString(R.string.circular_bold);
        CustomTypefaceSpan toolbarTypefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(toolbarFont, this);
        toolbarTitle.setSpan(toolbarTypefaceSpan, 0, toolbarTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        getActionBar().setTitle(toolbarTitle);
```

Here, `R.string.circular_bold` is

```
<string name="circular_bold">font/CircularStd-Bold.ttf</string>
```

And font is in `Asset/font` folder as displayed in image below

[image]

Below `CustomFontHelper` class helps to set `Typeface` to the text element-

```
public class CustomFontHelper {

    /**
     * Changing font of Paint element
     * @param paint text element of which font needs to be changed
     * @param font
     * @param context
     */
    public static void setCustomFont(Paint paint, String font, Context context) {
        if (font == null) {
            return;
        }
        Typeface typeface = FontCache.get(font, context);
        if (typeface != null) {
            paint.setTypeface(typeface);
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomTypefaceSpan` class is the actual class where font is applied to the text element.

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

    private String font;
    private Context context;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(@NonNull String font, @NonNull Context context) {
        super("");
        this.font = font;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(ds, font, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(paint, font, context);
    }
}
```

`FontCache` class is for caching the font, so same font can be reused
    public class FontCache {

```
    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<>();

    /**
     * Gets the typeface from Asset folder
     * @param name path to the font within asset folder
     * @param context context of the view
     * @return
     */
    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if (tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the point in marking negative?? I am already using it and it is working in my project perfectly