# Font Is Not Changing In Android Using "font" Resource File

Tags: android, android-resources, android-fonts

Following the new way of using fonts in Android Studio 3, I added font resource folder in res and added my `.ttf` fonts in it, then referencing them in the xml file like this:

```
                    <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/about_info"
                    android:textColor="@color/tin"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/diana" />
```

Compiles fine but doesn't work, the font isn't changing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976600/1915323

Answer (score 1):

You need to targeting on API level 26+ (Oreo) and support library 26.0.0+ installed in order to apply the font inside res/font.