# Loading a Font with PdfSharp .Net Standard preview from Xamarin.Forms fails: No appropriate font found

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, pdfsharp

I am currently assessing how to generate a PDF from Xamarin.Forms (currently running the app on Android, only) and checking the [.NET Standard port of PdfSharp](https://github.com/Didstopia/PDFSharp).

Drawing to the PDF and showing it works, but I'm having issues writing text to the document. When I am trying to load an `XFont` with the following code

```
var font = new XFont("sans-serif", 20);
```

it fails with the exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: No appropriate font found.

According to [these](https://github.com/roceh/PdfSharp.Xamarin/tree/master/Samples) samples, it is supposed to work this way, but they are for PdfSharp.Xamarin and not the PdfSharp .NET Standard. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/2249175) the `"sans-serif"` font family should be correct, but I've desperately tried other options, like `"Roboto"`, but to no avail.

Is PdfSharp for .NET Standard compatible with Xamarin at all? (It lists PdfSharp.Xamarin as a source it has been created from, hence I assumed it.) Is there anything else I have missed?

**EDIT**

I tried PdfSharp.Xamarin and it did work. Obviously this is an issue with the .NET Standard port.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar issue and i resolved it by writing my own implementation of `IFontResolver`  and assigning it to `GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver`.

```
public class FileFontResolver : IFontResolver // FontResolverBase
{
    public string DefaultFontName => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var fs = File.Open(faceName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public FontResolverInfo ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
    {
        if (familyName.Equals("Verdana", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (isBold && isItalic)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Fonts/Verdana-BoldItalic.ttf");
            }
            else if (isBold)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Fonts/Verdana-Bold.ttf");
            }
            else if (isItalic)
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Fonts/Verdana-Italic.ttf");
            }
            else
            {
                return new FontResolverInfo("Fonts/Verdana-Regular.ttf");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then tell PDFSharp to use it:

```
GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new FileFontResolver();
```

Comment: What do you do where the line fails? Something like this? `var font = new XFont(FontResolver("sans-serif", 20));`

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress No change needed when using the font. The FontResolver is a global setting and `new XFont(...)` will invoke it automatically. Just make sure you are using a font covered by your font resolver.

Answer (score -1):

if you got access denied for the above code. please replace the code with

```
public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(faceName))
            {
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76332709/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).