# How to filter "é" type char in android font

Tags: android, fonts

[image]

I added `avenir_next.otf` file in font resource.

I using this in `textview`

```
android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next"
```

How to avoid this Image type of font?

Comment: android only suuport ttf or wlf, font. So use only these type of fonts, than Text have that font :) check here

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/5110595)

Comment: @AshuKumar no android supports .otf files too

Comment: what is the expected result? How you expect it to look like?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I want "lete"