# How to set custom font in font_family.xml with attribute android:fontStyle="bold"

Tags: android, android-xml, font-family, android-fonts

I want to add custom bold font in my `font_family.xml`. I did not find bold `fontStyle="bold"` in [font family developer doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml). It only have `normal` or `italic` attribute. Here is `font_family.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

So i have to use style like

```
<style name="fontBoldStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_semi_bold</item>
</style>
```

or like this

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semi_bold"/>
```

**My question**

1. What does `fontStyle` attribute do? Even i did not provide italic font to `font_family.xml`, and set `textStyle="italic"` then my font is italic.
2. how to add custom bold font in font family and set `android:fontStyle="bold"` in `font_family.xml` so i dont have to create different styles and i just have to set `textStyle="bold"`

So what is a solution that i can set 3 of my fonts - `normal, bold, italic` to font_family.xml, and set `android:fontFamily="@font/font_family"` on TextView and then i can use `android:textStyle="bold"` or italic, or normal?

Comment: Use the Link [Bold in font Family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android). i think its work.

Comment: I have custom bold font.ttf so i dont use textStyle = "bold"

Comment: @IbadUrRahman i have already searched lot before asking, my question is not related to that. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: you question is quite confusing, you can do all the things you mentioned above so what is the problem exactly and is this question an opinion or about a problem you are facing. ?

Comment: I am editing my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Umair edited my question.

Comment: @Khemraj i believe there is no option for bold font yet. So what you can do is take a normal font and give font ="bold-font.ttf" so that your font will be normal but bold. Another way is to use textStyle everywhere which is a time consuming task. And the third option is to use styles for declaring your fonts. and then use those styles in your views.

Comment: I am currently doing styling, Thanks for effort @Umair

Answer (score 6):

For your **2nd question**:

You can add a custom bold font in a `font-family`, by defining a font with **`fontWeight="700"`**:

```
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        android:font="@font/montserrat_semi_bold" />
</font-family>
```

If a `TextView` uses this `font-family` with `textStyle="bold"`, it will show up in **montserrat_semi_bold**

Comment: Thanks bro, it is useful.

Comment: You're welcome. Took me a while to figure out, the official doc is really missing that part... 

Comment: Did you mean `android:textStyle="bold"`?

Comment: @GokhanArik, you're right! I updated the answer to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can do this by applying property called **`android:textStyle`** in your layout.xml
you can do this:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: What if i want set custom bold font to TextView dude?

Answer (score 0):

Setting font bold programatically this way

```
mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.ttf, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Or

```
mTextView.setTypeface(mTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
```

or You can use paint object and set it to text

Comment: Do you really think this is convenient way than styling? Also i can achieve this by just using textStyle="bold" or italic dude. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Why this is convenient way because you may change your theme or you may customize it or change font so it can be fesible

Comment: You should please read my question not only title dude. Your answer does not meet my requirement . I want use custom bold font in font_family.xml