# Not setting text bold in textview

Tags: android, textview, bold

I set some TextViews text bold in xml by:  android:textStyle="bold" 
The textviews which text isn't set in xml and binding from code are shown bold correct, but textviews which text is setted by xml don't show bold. Please help me to fix this bug.

Comment: Refer this link, you will find your answer from it:

[Make text bold in android textview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623508/android-textview-bold-and-italic-and-underline

Comment: I didn't find answer in this link. But I find where is the bug.I have 2 languages in my program(armenian and english).At  one tablet it works correct for both languages, in another it show bold when I choose english and don't show when the language is Armenian.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set text from both XML and Programmatically. If you set the text from XML in textview then it will be override by the text set as programmatically.So if you want to set text in textview you should set it Programmatically.