# How to make Colorful textview

Tags: android, textview, ondraw

Do you know easy way to make textview colorful as shown in below image ? I searched for it too much but I couldn't find anything useful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spannable String to Format the Text you like ..Here is the Queston in SO similar to your requirement but you need to increase the font height [Multi colored Text in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438371/how-do-i-get-show-text-in-my-text-view-with-bold-and-multi-coloured)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw all 10 digits yourself and show them as images...