# set one item in gridview to underlined on gridview load

Tags: android, gridview, underline

Ok so i have a gridview of strings and i want it so when i load the gridview i can have one underlined.

```
final GridView gridview = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                R.layout.customstyle, 
                letters );

        gridview.setNumColumns(COLUMNSIZE);
        gridview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
```

here is my gridview code, so how would i set one to underlined?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try with **custom** `adapter`   and pass  `SpannableString`  to `textview` .

```
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(textString);
text.setText(spanString);
```

Comment: @BrianPeach refer this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623508/android-textview-bold-and-italic-and-underline

Comment: Thanks for the link but i cant see how thats is relevent as there not using a gridview. 

i'd be happy to even have one item in the text view bold or change its background color on the load

Comment: the link for SpannableString , that you can apply while using custom adapter view