# Android two Textviews, align them as one paragraph

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, alignment, android-relativelayout

Lets say I have two `textviews`, a title, and details, the details is *toEndOf* the title (same line), and while the title is one line, the details, can be multiple, my question is, how can I configure the details `textview` that when it starts a new line, instead of aligning it to the previous row of the `textview`, align it to the title `textview`, hence creating a paragraph feel.

Please see these screenshot to understand what I'm trying to accomplish (the title is the bold text, details it the rest):

**Desired**:
[image]

**What I have so far:**

[image]

The only solution I can think of is using one `textview` for both, and format the text with HTML, but what if I need a bigger text size for the title?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to get and output like your big image using single textView? this is *my own example* if you like it, use it > http://stackoverflow.com/a/42081151/5188159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**SpannableText**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

This will do the job!

```
 <TextView
    ..
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    />
```

...

```
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
String head = "Seat (s):";
String body = "  The  baby name  means  the meaning of the nam";
setTextWithSpan(text,head+body,head, body,new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD));
```

Custom method

```
public  void setTextWithSpan(TextView textView, String text, String spanTextBold,String secondPartOfText,StyleSpan style) {

    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

    int start = text.indexOf(spanTextBold);
    int end = start + spanTextBold.length();
    sb.setSpan(style, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
    //sb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end ,0); // if you need a color

    int startTwo = text.indexOf(secondPartOfText);
    int endTwo = startTwo + secondPartOfText.length();
    // sb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC),startTwo,endTwo , 0);
    sb.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), startTwo, endTwo, 0);

    textView.setText(sb);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @who down vote this ? reason please ? if something wrong i can fix them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As you mentioned, I also see One `TextView` with different strings sizes/colors for texts inside.

To achieve this you need to use `SpannableString` - [Docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

Also Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335416/5993410) for details

Answer (score 0):

Use [SpannableText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-font-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview/16335416#16335416) for your issue to separate two textviews.