# Apply style only on selected string

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to set the complete string as set text and need to format specific substring using the following way:

```
int startSelection = binding.editText.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection = binding.editText.getSelectionEnd();
String selectedText = binding.editText.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
binding.editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>"+selectedText+"</i>"));
```

Comment: try to use style span on the string, you can use refer below example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623508/how-to-set-the-font-style-to-bold-italic-and-underlined-in-an-android-textview

Comment: Also you are only selecting subString you need to set the complete string again with formatting