# How to set underline text on textview?

Tags: android, textview

How to set underline text on `textview`?

I have used following code but it is not working.

```
tvHide.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><u>Hide post</u></p>").toString());
```

Comment: three ways to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout/27266015#27266015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I underline text in an android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of those questions because the OP is asking to underline a _textview_, not text itself.  Otherwise, his question title needs to be changed.  In other words, even if the textview is empty, it should still be underlined.. think of it as a border only on the bottom, but always there.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You  have to use [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) for that :

```
String mystring=new String("Hello.....");
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(mystring);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mystring.length(), 0);
yourtextview.setText(content);
```

Update : You can refer my answer on Underling TextView's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033316/to-draw-an-underline-below-the-textview-in-android/8033336#8033336) in all possible ways.

Comment: Just want to add one note here: While setting your span make sure you haven't use  textAllCaps = true. It won't work.

Comment: avoid giving a plain "0" when it expects flags, in most cases `Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` is the way to go.

Answer (score 92):

Following are the some approaches for underlined text in android:

**1st Approach**

You can define your string in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="your_string"><u>Underlined text</u></string>
```

And use that string in your `xml` file

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_underlined"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/your_string"/>
```

**Or** you can use that string in your Activity/Fragment

```
txtView.setText(R.string.your_string);
```

**2nd Approach**

To underline the text in TextView, you can use SpannableString

```
String text="Underlined Text";
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(text);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length(), 0);
txtView.setText(content);
```

**3rd Approach**

You can make use of setPaintFlags method of TextView to underline the text of TextView.

```
txtView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
txtView.setText("Underlined Text");
```

**4th Approach**

Make use of `Html.fromHtml(htmlString)`;

```
String htmlString="<u>Underlined Text</u>";
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

**Or**

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>underlined</u> text"));
```

**Note:**

If you have added this line `android:textAllCaps="true"` in your layout, then none of the above will work. For that, you have to define your string in Caps and then any of the above approach.

Comment: best and full answer to this question

Comment: Thanks, In my case I was using android:textAllCaps="true". due to which underline was not working.

Comment: way to change underline height?

Answer (score 49):

**Use this**

```
tvHide.setPaintFlags(tvHide.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: What about remove that underline?

Comment: This feels more concise than the SpannableString solution.  I wonder, does setting this paint flag just signal that the system should take care of the SpannableString setup, or is something entirely different happening?

Comment: This does not work for TextView with multiple lines. At least for me.

Comment: @PratikButani to disable: tvHide.setPaintFlags(0);

Answer (score 10):

Android supports string formatting using **HTML** tags in the strings xml. So the following would work:

```
<string name="label_testinghtmltags"><u>This text has an underscore</u></string>
```

Then you just use it as you normally would. You can see more in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

**Update:**

To further expand on the answer, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) says:

> ... the `format(String, Object...)` and `getString(int, Object...)` methods strip all the style information from the string. . The work-around to this is to write the HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with fromHtml(String), after the formatting takes place

For example, the resulting string from the following code snippet will **not** show up as containing underscored elements:

```
<string name="html_bold_test">This <u>%1$s</u> has an underscore</string>
String result = getString(R.string.html_bold_test, "text")
```

However the result from the following snippet **would** contain underscores:

```
<string name="html_bold_test">This &lt;u> %1$s &lt;/u> has an underscore</string>
String result = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_bold_test, "text"))
```

Answer (score 9):

Simple and easy way to display underline in `TextView` is:

```
yourTextView.getPaint().setUnderlineText(true);
```

And if you want to remove underlining for that view, you can write below code:

`yourTextView.getPaint().setUnderlineText(false);`

**It will work even though you set `android:textAllCaps="true"`**

Answer (score 7):

**Try this,**

```
tv.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 6):

you're almost there: just don't call `toString()` on `Html.fromHtml()` and you get a Spanned Object which will do the job ;)

```
tvHide.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><u>Hide post</u></p>"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Need not to use HTML properties, let's focus on java xD
I had the same problem, i found the way to do it in java:

```
String text="Hide post";
TextView tvHide=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(text);
spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
tvHide.setText(spanString );
```

Answer (score 5):

## Kotlin - normal code

```
val text = getString(R.string.welcome)

val spannableString = SpannableString(text).apply {
    setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length, 0)
}

text_view.text = spannableString
```

## Kotlin - extension

```
fun TextView.underline(resource: Int) {
    val text = context.getString(resource)
    val spannableString = SpannableString(text).apply {
        setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length, 0)
    }

    setText(spannableString)
}
```

usage:

```
text_view.underline(R.string.welcome)
```

## Kotlin - binding code

```
@BindingAdapter("underline")
fun underline(view: TextView, resource: Int) {
    if (resource == 0) return

    val text = view.context.getString(resource)
    val spannableString = SpannableString(text).apply {
        setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, text.length, 0)
    }

    view.text = spannableString
}
```

usage:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_report_problem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:underline="@{@string/common_report_problem}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to use [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html). You can find an example [here](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
tvHide.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><span style='text-decoration: underline'>Hide post</span></p>").toString());
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a View with the height of 1dp aligning start and the end of TextView, right below it. You can also use marginTop with negative value to make the underline closer to TextView. If you use your TextView and the under inside a relative layout, it would be much easier for alignments. here is the example:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewForgotPasswordUnderline"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:layout_below="@id/txtForgotPassword"
  android:layout_alignStart="@id/txtForgotPassword"
  android:layout_alignEnd="@id/txtForgotPassword"
  android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
  android:background="@color/lightGray" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
  android:id="@+id/txtForgotPassword"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:paddingTop="8dp"
  android:text="@string/userLoginForgotPassword"
  android:textColor="@color/lightGray"
  android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin: do it when you find ID

```
textview =findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview).also { it.paint?.isUnderlineText =true }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my `sign_in.xml` file I used this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/signuptextlinkbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="performSingUpMethod"
    android:text="Sign up now!"
    android:textColor="#5B55FF"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In my `SignIn.java` file, I used this:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
Button signuptextlinkbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signuptextlinkbtn);
signuptextlinkbutton.setPaintFlags(signuptextlinkbutton.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Now I can see my link underlined. It was simply text even thought I declared it as a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

I use BindingAdapters for things like this.

1. in a kotlin file you declare a bindingAdapter

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("underlineText")
   fun TextView.setUnderlineText(isVisible: Boolean){
        paintFlags = if(isVisible) paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG else paintFlags and Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG.inv()}
   ```

2. and then you use it inside your .xml layout

   ```
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/discount_label"
            underlineText="@{true}"
            android:text="underlined text"
            ...
            ...
             />
   ```