# How to Underline Text of Button in Android?

Tags: android, xml, button

I have a button which is transparent and has an icon and text.

I want to underline the text of the button but i have not been able to do this.

Below is my xml code:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/parkButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableStart="@drawable/park"
     android:text="@string/button_name"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

And the String file has:

```
<resources>
    <string name="button_name"><u>Parking Areas</u></string>
</resources>
```

This approach works in TextView, but not in Button.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Please have a look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033316/to-draw-an-underline-below-the-textview-in-android/8033336#8033336

Comment: Yes, i had already gone through this article. This is for textview in which case this works perfectly. But same method is not working for button text

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Code only**

Java:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.park);
button.setPaintFlags(button.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Kotlin:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.park);
button.paintFlags = button.paintFlags or Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
```

**Resource string with static text (xml only)**

If you have a static text in your resources you could also use the following approach in your `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="underlined_text"><u>I\'m underlined</u></string>
```

**Resource string with dynamic text (xml + code)**

If you're using dynamic text but don't like the first approach (which isn't the best imho either), you could also use following:

strings.xml

```
<string name="underlined_dynamic_text"><u>%s</u></string>
```

Java:

```
button.setText(getString(R.string.underlined_dynamic_text, "I'm underlined");
```

Kotlin:

```
button.text = getString(R.string.underlined_dynamic_text, "I'm underlined")
```

Comment: Took me a long time to come back ! But gaining more experience on Android by now, I realized that this solution would have worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 16):

This should make your *ButtonText* **bold**, **underlined** and ***italic*** at the same time.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="register"><u><b><i>Copyright</i></b></u></string>
</resources>
```

To set this String to your TextView, do this in your **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/register" />
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between yours and mine code. This is a direct copy of an answer from another stackflow article. did not not work

Comment: This chunk of code worked for buttons as well. What OS version you are using?

Comment: How to set another resource string like @string/something instead of Copyright literal?

Answer (score 6):

You can't set underline from xml file. To set underline using code you need to set the underline flag on button.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.park);
button.setPaintFlags(button.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: I tried your code. But got an error in  Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG - any idea?

Comment: try adding import android.graphics.Paint. If you are still getting error, share error details

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        String styledText = "<u>parking areas</u>";
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.park);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Content");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
button.setText(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Compose you can use the **`textDecoration`** attribute in the `Text`:

```
Button(
    onClick = {}
) {
    Icon(
        Icons.Filled.Add,
        contentDescription = "Add",
    )
    Text(
        text = "Button",
        textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline
    )
}
```

[image]