# how to underline text within a button using a style

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml, android-button, android-styles

Is there a way to underline the text in a Button using a style?
I can do it by wrapping the text in `strings.xml` with html tags like this

```
<string name="my_text"><u>My underlined text</u></string>
```

But I rather have it like this

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    <!-- not working --> android:textStyle="underline"
    android:text="@string/my_text" />
```

and ideally I would define the style in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <!-- not working --><item name="android:textStyle">underline</item>
</style>
```

And I know I could probably make my own custom Button that will have the text underlined. But that feels like it would take a lot of effort for something so basic.

**Edit**
My question was marked as possible duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718707/how-to-underline-text-of-button-in-android), but I'm trying to achieve underlining via styling.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is only those two ways

- using `<u> </u>`
- `button.setPaintFlags(button.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't define it with a style (`underline` doesn't exist).
Just use:

```
MaterialButton button = findViewById(R.id.xxxxx);
button.setPaintFlags(button.getPaintFlags() |   Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

[image]