# Android - Hyperlink missing underline

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, linkify

I use linkify to make a textview work as hyperlink, and it does work nicely. The only issue is the underline is missing, could anyone point me out what could cause the problem? shouldn't the underline come by default?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Spannable params

```
addLinks(Spannable text,...)
```

[linkify class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

[SpannableStringBuilder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)

-replying to comment-
SpannableStringbuilder implements CharSequence, which can be used in TextView.setText();
So once you finish making your underlined text, you can use TextView.setText() and still use the method your are using.

Or refer to this: [How to set underline text on textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645789/how-to-set-underline-text-on-textview)

Comment: I use addLinks(TextView text, Pattern p, String scheme, Linkify.MatchFilter matchFilter, Linkify.TransformFilter transformFilter)

Comment: I figured out that it's because I used UrlSpan instead of UnderlineSpan... is that possible I can set both?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the SpannableStringBuilder class, you can set as many spans as you want, as long as they don't override each other.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can retrieve the existing SpannableString from a textView so that I can add the new span to it?

Comment: String yourString=someTextView.getText().toString();

Comment: I tried: Spannable s = (Spannable) myTextView.getText(); s.setSpan(...); s.setSpan(...), but it doesn't work

Comment: please set as answer if you got it you work. check the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xml attribute `autoLink="web"` for the `TextView` widget to automatically detect if the content is a web address. Here is an example:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textColorLink="@color/hyperlink_blue"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

The attribute `textColor` is for text other than hyperlinks, which will be 'black' in the above example and the attribute `textColorLink` is for any text that takes a form of a hyperlink - which will be blue per above.

You can also append other autoLink values by 'piping' them together:

```
android:autoLink="web|email|map|phone"
```

This works for `TextView`, `AppCompatTextView` (SupportV7/AppCompat), `AppCompatTextView` (androidx/AppCompat)