# Remove a Paint Flag in Android

Tags: android, bitwise-operators

My code looks like this:

```
    TextView task_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_text);
    task_text.setPaintFlags( task_text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

This causes a strike through effect to appear on the text. However, I'd like to know how to remove the flag once set, and how to detect that the flag is set.

I understand this is a bitwise operation, but I've tried both ~ and - operators, neither work.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

To remove a flag, this should work:

```
task_text.setPaintFlags( task_text.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Which means set all the set flags, except of `Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG`.

To check if a flag is set (Edit: for a moment I forgot it is java...):

```
if ((task_text.getPaintFlags() & Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) > 0)
```

Comment: Another easy solution is simply to use the various methods provided on Paint :)

Answer (score 32):

In Kotlin

```
task_text.paintFlags = task_text.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for me! `tvPhone.autoLinkMask = Linkify.ALL`, then `tvPhone.text = "1-800-12345"`, then `tvPhone.paintFlags = tvPhone.paintFlags and Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG.inv()`

Answer (score 29):

This also works:

```
task_text.setPaintFlags(0);
```

Comment: I think this is a strange case where not using the correct is more corret, cause there is no reason to check for conditions here, you just want 2 cases, set the Paint.Flag or to remove it, great solution.

Comment: Don't do this. This removes ALL flags, not just a particular one.

Answer (score 10):

Use **exclusive OR** operator `^` instead of `|` with `&(~)` combination:

```
// setup STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG flag if current flags not contains it
task_text.setPaintFlags(task_text.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));

// second call will remove STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
task_text.setPaintFlags(task_text.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Check if flag is currently setup:

```
if((task_text.getPaintFlags() & Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) == Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sergey This is the only robust answer here. 1) Check if the flag you want to remove is present. 2) If it is, remove it using an XOR. I wish users would stop upvoting answers that involve setting the paintFlags to 0 or using XOR before checking if the flag to remove is present.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, 
just set its default flag is a better choice. Otherwise, the text will be looked jagged. The default flag in TextView (EditText extends TextView) is

```
Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
```

And set a new paintflag will replace the previous one. I have made a test to verify it. So, just like this:

```
task_text.setPaintFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 6):

|--------------------------------------------------|
|<*>| Underline with a textView :
|--------------------------------------------------|

|*| Add Underline :

```
 txtVyuVar.setPaintFlags(txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

---

|*| Remove Underline :

```
txtVyuVar.setPaintFlags(txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

---

|*| Check Underline :

```
if((txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() & Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG) == Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)
{
    // Codo Todo
}
```

---

|*| Toggle Underline :

```
if((txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() & Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG) == Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG)
{
    txtVyuVar.setPaintFlags(txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
}
else
{
    txtVyuVar.setPaintFlags(txtVyuVar.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView details_actual_price;
//and find id from your xml file

details_actual_price.setPaintFlags(details_actual_price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

//used for adapter calss

Textview details_actual_price;
// and find id
holder.actulPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.actulPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the above mentioned methods in kotlin using kotlin bitwise operators and I was getting weird results...

so to remove a flag I just did

```kotlin
view.paintflags = 0x00
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

to set "strike thru" flag:

```
numberTextView?.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

to remove this flag:

```
numberTextView?.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).