# AlertDialog title underline color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-titlebar

Is there a way to change the color of the title underline in an AlertDialog?
I already changed the title color through a custom style definition (see below), but I didn't found any xml attribute for the underline.

```
    <style name="CustomTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
    </style>
```

I'm running Android 4.

Edit: That's how I create the AlertDialog

```
        Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
            R.style.DialogPrivate));
    ad.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

    ad.setMessage("blaaaaa");
    ad.setPositiveButton("test", null);
    ad.setNegativeButton("test2", null);
    ad.show();
```

And how it looks like at the moment [Screenshot](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/2797/tkyauy9i_png.htm)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: Do you know how I can access the title TextView? I'm using the default AlertDialog, didn't extend it.

Answer (score 2):

The underline is actually a View object with its background color set to the default holo blue (on jellybean atleast).

You can see the layout for alert dialogs at: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_holo.xml#L58. Specifically, the titleDivider view:

```
<View android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
```

Thats unfortunate, because it means there's no way to customise the color of the view without some ugly, hacky code such as:

```
void changeUnderlineColor(AlertDialog d, int color) {
    final ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) d.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    v.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android")).setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

This works on Jellybean using the holo_light theme, but it's almost certainly a bad idea. If you really want to change the color of the line, looks like you'll need to build a completely custom Dialog yourself

Answer (score 1):

This response is a bit late, but I believe that the "underline" is actually part of a 9 patch image file used as a background.  You will need to change that background image to change the color.

Answer (score -1):

try using android:textColorLink="#783302"

Comment: Unfortunately the color stays the same with this attribute.
<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/privateColor</item>