# android: how to add Underline in the String

Tags: android, string, textview

```
<string-array name="myarray">    
<item>Apple</item> 
<item>Banana</item> 
<item>Grape</item>
<item>Melon</item>
```

if i want to add Underline the "Banana" what should I add?

Comment: [This has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2394939/420015)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `SpannableString` by which you can do Underline, Strike, Highlight, Bold, Italic etc to the text

for Underline you have to use `UnderlineSpan` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan.html

```
 TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
 SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Apple Banana Grape Melon");
 content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 6, 11, 0);
 textview.setText(content);
```

or simply by adding HTML tag to the resource string `<string name="sample"> <u>your data</u></string>`

Comment: This string will I show the button text, so if the button is clicked it will display the button text "Apple", "Banana", "Grape" and appeared Underline the words "Banana"

Comment: see updated answer, you have mold code according to requirement. I just shown you different way.

Answer (score 3):

```
<resource>
    <string name="your_string_here">This is an <u>underline</u>.</string>
</resources>
```