# Set underline text to TextView in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to know how to set underline text to TextView in android? Please make a note that I don't have capability to set a strings.xml with pre-populated strings is there any way to add it with pure java code in Android.

Comment: Please, take a look at this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: 6 Ways - [Underline a TextView In Android](https://androidride.com/underline-a-textview-in-android/)

Answer (score 128):

Try this code:

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: what about remove underline?

Comment: textview.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL);

Comment: This one is best solution, Every one should use this code, a one line workable code. Thanks keep it Up

Answer (score 23):

**Kotlin way**

```
textview.paintFlags = Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG
```

Comment: This disrupts the font better to use spannableString

Answer (score 22):

Here is the simplest way

```
TextView theTextView = new TextView(this);

theTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>Text to underline</u>"));
```

Comment: Method "fromHtml" was deprecated

Answer (score 21):

Just try this:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
SpannableString mySpannableString = new SpannableString("My String");
mySpannableString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, mySpannableString.length(), 0);
myTextView.setText(mySpannableString);
```

Answer (score 9):

i don't know if somebody is still interested in this topic, but i disovered that

`textview.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL);` did not work for me.

My solution was this snippet `textView.setPaintFlags(0);`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is **Kotlin extension to underline** text

```
fun String.underLine(): SpannableString {
    val spanStr = SpannableString(this)
    spanStr.setSpan(UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanStr.length, 0)
    return spanStr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin ..
put underline for textview or String
Using HtmlCompat.fromHtml() method

```
val html = "<u> The text you want to underline </u>"
textview11.text = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

for layout xml

```
<string name="text_underline"><u> The text you want to underline </u></string>
```