# How do I Underline Specific text in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Don&apos;t worry we will never share this with anyone\nBy Clicking register you are indicating that you have read and agreed to the \n **Terms of services**  and **Privacy Policy**"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
        android:textSize="8.5sp"
    />
```

From the above code I need to underline Terms of Services and Privacy Policy which are being highlighted bold.

I had tried using `<u></u>` but doesn't worked.

Also I need to increase the font of Terms of Service, Privacy Policy only

Please do give some suggestions.

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your text in `strings.xml` file.Yes,you can define formatted html in it too.

So you can try this out:

```
<string name="nice_html">
<![CDATA[Don&apos;t worry we will never share this with anyone<br/>
By Clicking register you are indicating that you have read and agreed to the <br/>
 <u>Terms of services</u>  and <u>Privacy Policy</u>
]]></string>
```

Then, in your code:

`TextView foo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.foo);`
`foo.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.nice_html)));`

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235131/set-textview-text-from-html-formatted-string-resource-in-xml/3237438#3237438).

This is the cleanest way to do it.Inshallah.

Comment: Also I need to increase the font of Terms of Service, Privacy Policy only

Answer (score 0):

```
String mString=new String("Don&apos;t worry we will never share this with anyone\nBy Clicking register you are indicating that you have read and agreed to the \n **Terms of services**  and **Privacy Policy**");
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(mString);
span.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), index of T in terms, mString.length(), 0);
mTextView.setText(span);
```