# How do I programatically add a line below a textview layer

Tags: android

I am looking to add a line below a textView programmatically in java and not in xml.
I have the textView as follows:

```
textView.setText(DisplayName);
```

How do I go about the same? I have a textview supporting text and checkbox and I would like ot add a line below the same. Any clue?

Thanks!
Justin

Comment: Could you put more code please?

Comment: Do you mean like line for the text?

Comment: I meant a line below the textview layer. like a <view in xml or a divider

Comment: If you mean you just want a 2nd line of text in that textbox, just do DisplayName+"\n"+second_string.  If you want to add in a new textView below this one, you'll need to create one via new and add it to the parent of this with the correct layout parameters.

Comment: Can you show me via code, how to set a line below a textview, with something like textview.setlinebelow( r.drawable.line)

Comment: Underline in a textview ?

Comment: no, not underline a seperator/divider

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for a separator. You could achieve this by 'faking' a line-seperator. add a normal View to your parent view with a height of 1dp.

[Android - Dynamically Add Views into View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216547/android-dynamically-add-views-into-view)

**If you load a view from xml and want to add the line programmatically:**

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ViewGroup layout = vi.inflate(R.layout.MyParentLayout, null);

View separator = new View(Context context);
```

set the view its layoutparams set its height: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

```
layout.addView(separator);
```

**If you create your layout programmatically:**

new LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);` //or whatever kind of layout you want

*I am writing this post on my mobile phone so it could contain some errors.*

Comment: I get the error for inser_point and addview related to inserpoint

Comment: Could you show me the exact error? I will update my answer with a code snippet in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Add line view to the parent layout after textview.

```
View ruler = new View(myContext); ruler.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
parentLayout.addView(ruler, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
```

Comment: It shows error on myContext and parentLayout(where it asks me to create the same fields). Can you please suggest a way to fix the same or what myContext is with respect to my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to underline the text, try this (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947374/413254):

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

If you're trying to create a divider of sorts, go with what RajaReddy suggested.

Comment: I am trying to create a divider below the textview, so far none of the answers are working