# how do i underline every character and set number of characters dynamically in a edit view

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, styling, underline

i want to give hint for last 4 characters only.Please provide layout for the same

[image]

Comment: Did you take a look already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: check spanable style in android. that will help

Comment: @tim Yes,I already had a look at that link.This is not I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
TextView theTextView = new TextView(this);

theTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>3</u> <u>2</u> <u>3</u> <u>5</u> <u>1</u>"));
```