# How to create a Textview with underline text in android

Tags: android

I want to create a `TextView` with underline text . Please suggest me how to create in layout file . Find the image bellow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kcTN.png

Comment: a lil bit searching led me to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: checkout [Underlining text in TextView](http://www.androidgig.com/tip-underlining-text-in-textview/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout

Comment: Use _Spannable_ string

Comment: [6 ways - Underline A TextView In Android](https://androidride.com/underline-a-textview-in-android/)

Answer (score 6):

add this line to your code

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: This is does not make the underline the same color as text

Comment: Yes, I think you wont be able to change the underline color.

Answer (score 0):

```
SpannableString spanStr = new SpannableString("Your String");
    spanStr.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanStr.length(), 0);

yourTextView.setText(spanStr);
```