# Underlining text in Android that persists across a string replace

Tags: android, string, replace, underline

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout) works perfectly for my text... the first time. I have some resource file-defined strings:

```
<string name="permission_replace">PERMISSION</string>
<string name="warn_permission">This app needs PERMISSION to work properly. Update in <u>settings</u>.</string>
```

The `<u>` tags work properly the first time I display the text, but when I go to replace my placeholder (`"PERMISSION"`) the underline gets lost. Here's how I'm doing the replacement:

```
warnPermissionText.setText(warnPermissionText.getText().toString().replaceAll(getString(R.string.permission_replace),"some permission text"));
```

How can I retain the underline tags through the replacement? Or do I just have to programmatically add them back in? I'm not sure what magic does the formatting on the first go 'round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you call `toString()`, you are saying "hey, get rid of all that nice formatting that I had in there".

[The `TextUtils` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) has a number of utility methods that can be applied directly to a `CharSequence`, and therefore should retain formatting. In your case, [the `replace()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.CharSequence[])) should work, at least for simple cases.

In your specific case, you could also use [the N-parameter form of `getString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)), if you change `This app needs PERMISSION to work properly. Update in <u>settings</u>.` to `This app needs %s to work properly. Update in <u>settings</u>.` and supply the value for `%s` in the `getString()` call.