# How to have an Android Button with only a bottom border?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my resource xml file, I am trying to have a button that looks like the "Resend Code" in the image below.
My strategy has been to use a button and give it the same background as the background color of the screen and add a bottom border only.
How should I add the bottom border ? 
PS: The button in question is the "Resend Code" below the "Cancel". 
[image]

Comment: Please share your xml code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I underline text in an Android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Textview and underline to get the same look like your design

Either you can use

```
mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
mTextView.setText("Resend Code");
```

Or you can use

```
String htmlString="<u>Resend Code</u>";
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

For button, you should make a string resource as

```
<string name="underlined_dynamic_text"><u>%s</u></string>
```

and use this as a

```
button.setText(getString(R.string.underlined_dynamic_text, "Resend Code");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background(the image resource) of the button to only be the border.

But if I were to reproduce that "Resend Code". I would just use a TextView with an underline.