# How to remove phone number underline?

Tags: java, android-layout, textview, underline

I tried many technique to remove phone number underline  but without success, this is not for web view or URL, the current textview is:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Blue"
        android:text="mobile" />
```

Comment: For some reason, I am not facing the same issue with your code. Can you please share your java code snippet too? Thanks.

Comment: my code is fine but it gives underline to phone number, I want to remove underline to phone number.. thank you for helping and let me know

Answer (score -1):

- You can check and reverse adding underline in Textview 
  (ref: [Can I underline text in an Android layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394935/can-i-underline-text-in-an-android-layout))
- Remove if you are using underline dynamic text in your code or a string resource xml file, which supports HTML tags like `<b></b>, <i></i>` and `<u></u>`.

Comment: What I want is to Remove the underline, the underline is not going away, and the code is not for web ui android, I am using it in android application , thank you for helping and let me know if you know any technique to remove the underline.