# Rectangle shape drawable, specify top and bottom stroke colors?

Tags: android

Is there any way to define a top and bottom stroke for a gradient, or create a compound shape drawable?:

```
// option1:
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient
    android:startColor="#f00"
    android:endColor="#0f0"
    />
  <stroke
    top=1dip, yellow
    bottom=1dip, purple
    />
</shape>

// option2
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    height=1dip, color=yellow />

  <gradient
    android:startColor="#f00"
    android:endColor="#0f0"
    />

  <shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    height=1dip, color=purple />
</shape>
```

I don't think either are possible?

Thanks

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Answer (score 10):

I guess, it can be done by using [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).

Following is the **res/drawable/layer_list_shape.xml**

I have used hard-coded dimensions..

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="150dp" android:height="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="6dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:width="150dp" android:height="50dp"/>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#0f0"
            android:startColor="#f00" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="82dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:width="150dp" android:height="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff0" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**res/layout/main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/layer_example" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of any way to make this possible in XML.

But you always have the option to do the drawing on your own...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)

Answer (score 1):

building up on the answer given by Vijay C, you can create a drawable and include in any layout. The previous answer was ok but it added hard-coded dimensions which made it impossible to be used in background as wrap_content. Also, this way you reduce the number of items from 3 to 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d8dae3" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:startColor="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use hardcoded dimensions it's possible to use 3 views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip" 
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/header" />

<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip" 
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The header element has a gradient background. Of course, you could use any other layout as well.