# Changing position of a button

Tags: android, coordinates, absolutelayout

I have one button in an AbsoluteLayout in an XML file. From there I am able to set the (x,y) position of the button.

How can I get and set the (x,y) coordinates of the button programmatically?

Thanks all.

Comment: Related post - [Android - How to place a button on a specific position on different screen densities with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9791194/465053)

Answer (score 10):

You have to get a reference to you button, for example by calling [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). When you got the reference to the button you can set the x and y value with button.[setX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29) and button.[setY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setY%28float%29).

```
....
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.<id of the button in the layout xml file>);
myButton.setX(<x value>);
myButton.setY(<y value>);
....
```

Comment: it says the method setX(int) is undefined for the type Button.

Comment: Mh, that's weird. The Button class extends the View class and there you can find the both methods setX() and setY(). Try this instead: View myButton = (View) findViewById(R.id.<id of the button in the layout xml file>);

Comment: we have methods for all the properties, but dnt have any method to set x and y for the buttons or other widgets. :(

Comment: dint set for view either..i am using 2.2 google sdk. is it anything to do with the sdk version??

Comment: Check out the method [layout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: yeah..i tried in 3.0 honeycomb, it works..but how do i make it work in lower versions..i cant make an app in higher version coz it wont b useful for devices wid lower version OS..

Comment: i got the solution.. offsetLeftAndRight() and offsetTopAndBottom() works..but if we specify the co-ordinates in xml, it wont work..otherwise it works properly..thanks a lot for ur time and support..

Comment: yes..i tried and it seems like working, provided we dont give co-ordinates in xml in this case also..but i really dnt understand how this l, r, t, b thing works..i gave all 10, and it appeared on top left corner

Comment: Didn't work, create 12 buttons with various values passes to setX and setY. See one massive button in the WRONG place.

Answer (score 5):

The answer you're looking for is in [`LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.html). Firstly, I'd suggest *not* using AbsoluteLayout -- it's deprecated -- and using something else, maybe a FrameLayout, and just using the left and top margins as your x and y offsets.

However, to answer your question:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
absParams.x = myNewX;
absParams.y = myNewY;
button.setLayoutParams(absParams);
```

Or alternatively:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams,
    myNewX, myNewY));
```

Answer (score 0):

hummm u can try this. . . 
[Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)
Just go threw this site u will get the Sollution. If not then reply to me.
And if its help u then give me a vote.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the layout-method of the View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#layout(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)