# how to move dynamically created TextView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, position, android-framelayout

I'm working on on demo of drag and drop. In that I created some dynamic `TextView` on `FrameLayout` and now I want to move that `TextView` on that `FrameLayout`. So please please tell me any proper way to that...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: how is your frameLayout moving?

Comment: Sorry..I corrected my question..

Comment: So is it not working with setLayoutParams?

Comment: can this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646929/changing-position-of-a-button

Comment: Have you tried? post some code...

Answer (score 0):

try it out

```
MarginLayoutParams params=(MarginLayoutParams )poi.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin=80;

 params.topMargin=50;
    poi.setLayoutParams(params);
```