# Android - How to move a button programmatically

Tags: android, button

I want to move a button depending on where the widgets are on the screen

Comment: What you want to do is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646929/changing-position-of-a-button. But you may want to consider other options like a dynamic relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can move a button by using the

```
button.setY(Float)
button.setX(Float)
```

For example, on your Activity, you can do something like this. (This is done using Kotlin).

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var button: Button // Call it up here

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post)

        button = findViewById(R.id.ButtonsId) // Choose which button from your xml file. 

    }

    //Whichever your action function is {
            button.setX(225F) // This will move the button horizontally. 
            button.setY(225F) // This will move the button vertically once the action is performed.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can obviously decide what number you want to set it as.

Answer (score -1):

Use `translationX` and `translationY` - [View.setTranslationX(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTranslationX(float))