# Buttons/Images in Java and their positioning (android app) Problem

Tags: java, android, button

I'm am currently developing an app but came across a problem.
I want to have a Button or Image that I can move around. In the background, I have 3 "zones" where the Button/Image could be placed.

I don't know what to look for. I have searched the Internet for things like

- https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement
- Track X and Y coorinate of a button
- Position of a Button  Container with button
- Button position after moving

([Android Studio button positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051477/android-studio-button-positioning))

I have searched for many things but cannot find a proper solution.
Please be so kind and share links with me on how to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

** SOLVED **

What i needed was Drag an Drop buttons

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to implement a custom `GLSurfaceView` where you have a `canvas` to draw your different regions, and can also track movements. have a look here:
[Displaying graphics with OpenGL ES](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl) 
[Respond to touch events](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch)