# How to change the position of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

Could you please tell me how to change the position of my JButton? I tried all the functions that I found on web, like setLocation() and more, but I'm still stuck.

```
    JButton b3 = new JButton();
    f.setSize(600,500); 
    b3.setVisible(true);
    b3.setText("admin area");
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(b3);
    f.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646929/changing-position-of-a-button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` :

> A flow layout arranges components in a directional flow, much like lines of text in a paragraph
>
> -- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html

If you don't want to have your buttons in one row, you should use another layout manager. The `GridBagLayout` is my favorite for complex layout but is not the easiest to use. If you want to position your buttons with absolute coordinates, then you can just apply a `null` layout.

```
f.setlayout(null);
button.setBounds(...);
f.add(button);
```