# Android Glowing Border

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, border, glow

i was creating a border using this example:

[Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

I was wonder is there anyway to make the border glow?
I want it to kind of look like this:
https://g1.gstatic.com/android/market/com.feelingtouch.glowsnake/ss-480-4-4

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just make a 9-patch and use it as the background.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: How to make the border glow?

Comment: The link is no longer working. Any other suggestions?