# how to add bottom border in relativelayout

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/settings_border" android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="15dip" android:layout_marginTop="5dip">
            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/map_refresh"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:background="@drawable/settings_selector_up" 
                android:padding="15dp">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/Text1" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Map refresh period">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView09" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 min" 
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp">
                </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/own_location" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/settings_selector_mid">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/Text1" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Own location update period">
                </TextView>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView09" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 min" 
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp">
                </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

I want set only bottom border in relativelayout. I want to dispaly listview style but not using listview. Lets say each listitem is relativlayout. I want set only bottom border so its look like a listview's divider.

Comment: Here's my answer to a very similar question. Problem is solved with a lightweight straightforward library. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30802089/3649279

Comment: please try my ans here [BorderedRelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45959525/6258971)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope I understood what you said.

in the res folder create a new folder (if you don't already have it) named drawable

there create an xml named "borders.xml"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:angle="90" android:centerColor="#6da23f" android:endColor="#8bc45d" android:startColor="#2f481c" />

            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#999999" />

            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />

            <corners android:radius="10px"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="90" android:centerColor="#6da23f" android:endColor="#8bc45d" android:startColor="#4c8a39" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="6dp" />

            <corners android:radius="10px"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You can further edit it as you like.
Then select the layout from the Outline and click Background properties, and select the borders xml that you created.

This will create borders for all 4. Alternatively, you can add a simple

```
<View android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

line and add it to the bottom of your layout and change the color/size to your liking.

Comment: It makes all 4 borders visible, not just bottom.

Answer (score 11):

For some reason the other solutions didn't work for me - all borders were shown no matter how I changed it. This worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/gray" />
            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The color of the **border is gray** and the **background is white** for the container (LinearLayout in my example). You can simply change the second item to make the border thicker or have border on the top/left/right.

This is how the layout xml looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_gray_border"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
            style="@style/EditTextSearch"
            android:hint="@string/find"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I got the idea from here: [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

Comment: i just want to add bottom border, it added all 4 borders.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, finally, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#FF8000" />

    <solid 
        android:color="#00FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"/>

    <corners android:radius="10px"/>

    <padding 
        android:left="10dip" 
        android:top="10dip" 
        android:right="10dip" 
        android:bottom="10dip" /> 
</shape>
```

You can save this as `borderframe.xml` in the res/drawable folder (create it if it doesnt exist yet), and reference it like so: `android:background="@drawable/borderframe"`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to display a border is to create a horizontal `LinearLayout`, and to set its background color and height according to the border you want.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea : a LinearLayout is not meant to be used to make borders...

Comment: Is a simple way, and you get some properties on your border.