# How do I create an input box using Android's Layout mechanism?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Using Android's Layout mechanism, how do I create an input box with the password icon, and a split between the icon and the input field, as shown below?  I'd like to have the border around the input field as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This ....

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_margin="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="#dbdbdb" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

@drawable/background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fafafa" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#dbdbdb" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use imageview and an edit text inside a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_280sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:id="@+id/rl_password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/key"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/iv_password"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_password"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i want a line as well as border around all of it.

Comment: for border there are several methods, but i'll suggest you making a custom drawable. you can search google for best suitable method for you i.e., here's a link to recommended method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111402/how-can-i-create-a-border-around-an-android-linearlayout

Comment: and to add a line as separator (not as in this picture), you can use <View> tag in your XML file

Comment: I know this way but is there another better way to do it like direct through some xml vector file? and please see image properly there is a line in between text and icon. @Rishbh Sehgal

Comment: hey i suggested you the best possible way, just check with the link i shared, and yeah i saw the image properly , you just need to implement some logic in your xml designs and thats all done.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you will not find a tutorial here.
we guys here don't put tutorial if you have any problem in implementing your code you can ask.
for now, you can watch this [tutrial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-I67MNRQZM) may help.