# shape drawable on Android

Tags: android, shapes

I use shape drawable to draw a background as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#888888"
        android:endColor="#888888"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="4dip"
        android:topRightRadius="4dip"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#666666"
        android:dashWidth="10dip"
        android:dashGap="0dip" />
</shape>
```

I want to set the bottom edge without stroke.
How can I modify it?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457135/how-to-add-border-around-linear-layout-except-at-the-bottom if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:bottom="3dip"
                android:left="3dip"
                android:right="3dip"
                android:top="3dip" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="6dip"
                android:topRightRadius="6dip" />

            <solid android:color="#666666" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#888888"
                android:startColor="#888888" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```