# How to create a border around linear layout like the image below?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

How to create a border around linear layout like the image below ? [image]

Comment: check this post 
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457135/how-to-add-border-around-linear-layout-except-at-the-bottom

Comment: What about using a 9 patch?

Comment: If you cant see  the image here then you can find the image at this link - http://postimg.org/image/i7e1s8k2x/

Comment: This does not conform to Android UI guidelines. Sectioned content should look similar to [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/Images/preferences_dialog.png).

Comment: But still i want to create a border like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this layout xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#8106a9"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lin_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:background="#8106a9"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="Sim Card"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

and lin_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />
```

then i get a layout like below

I hope this will help you

[image]

Comment: unfortunately 'layout_alignTop' is obsolete now.