# Add only top and bottom border on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-shape

I would like to add only a bottom and a top border on my `Linearlayout`. 
I have tried to do this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But it add a border around the shape..

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Better use a 9 patch in this case. just draw the upper and lower borders and leave the right and left borders transparent. Of course, excluding the 9 patch markers.

Comment: You can follow [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make this **two file** and put **this code**. you can set border top and bottom border,

**main.xml**

```
<TextView
      android:text="This is textline"
      android:background="@drawable/border_set"
/>
```

**border_set.xml**

This file located into full path `project_root/res/drawable/border_set.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />

        </shape>
   </item>

   <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"> 
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. There is a border all around the shape. I have updated my post

Comment: @wawanopoulos This does not work for me too. I think you should un-accept the answer. This is mis-leading

Comment: He also took his answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view

Comment: This is a version that works for bottom-border: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19239478/4975760

Comment: What if I wanted border top to be different color than border bottom?

Comment: @sachinjain024 It would work after remove the stroke.

Answer (score 30):

I think you can create this drawable and use it as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp" android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Think of is as drawing a rectangle with border color first and then lay on top of it a rectangle with your background color leaving out 1dp on top and at the bottom.

Comment: Won't it have an overhead in painting?

Answer (score 22):

Here is the solution. It works even with transparent background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="-2dp"  android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/borderColor" />
            <solid android:color="@color/backgroundColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: <solid/> is used to set background color

Answer (score 19):

I believe this is the simplest way:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#000000" />
```

Comment: The normal color of the divider is gray and it's thinner so this would be better.       

<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:background="#efefef" />

Answer (score 10):

This is my version; top border and bottom border are visible, not showing the left or right borders. And the background is transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="1dp">

    <item
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="-1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/BlueGrey_colorPrimary" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick way to achieve this:

- Add a Text View to the bottom and/or top of your layout.
- Set the TextView's width to "match_parent"
- Set the TextView's height to about "1dp" or find the thickness you would like
- Set the TextView's background to the color you would like the border to be

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. Draw 3 shapes like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/menu_line_separator_in" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/menu_line_separator_out" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/menu_line_separator_out" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: what is the differences between *menu_line_separator_in* and *menu_line_separator_out*? say that I want to draw black line on top and bottom. I think **menu_line_separator_out** just a black color. But, how about **menu_line_separator_in**?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this link [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

I expect that you are solve from this link.
also you can solve [How to add border around linear layout except at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457135/how-to-add-border-around-linear-layout-except-at-the-bottom)